# C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-declaration

What is the difference between the following declarations:

```
int* arr1[8];
int (*arr2)[8];
int *(arr3[8]);
```

What is the general rule for understanding more complex declarations?

Comment: Here is a great article about reading complex declarations in C: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: @jesper Unfortunately, the `const` and `volatile` qualifiers, which are both important and tricky, are missing in that article.

Answer (score 475, accepted):

```
int* arr[8]; // An array of int pointers.
int (*arr)[8]; // A pointer to an array of integers
```

The third one is same as the first.

The general rule is [operator precedence](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html). It can get even much more complex as function pointers come into the picture.

Comment: So, for 32 bit systems:
int* arr[8]; /* 8x4 bytes allocated, for each pointer */
int (*arr)[8]; /* 4 bytes allocated, only a pointer */

Comment: Nope. int* arr[8]: 8x4 bytes allocated *total*, 4 bytes for each pointer. int (*arr)[8] is right, 4 bytes.

Comment: I should have re-read what I wrote. I meant 4 for each pointer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The reason that the first one is the same as the last is that it's always allowed to wrap parentheses around declarators. P[N] is an array declarator. P(....) is a function declarator and *P is a pointer declarator. So everything in the following is the same as without any parentheses (except for the one of the functions' "()": int (((*p))); void ((g(void))); int *(a[1]); void (*(p())).

Comment: Well done in your explanation.  For an in-depth reference on precedence and associativity of operators refer to page 53 of The C Programming Language (ANSI C second edition) by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.  The operators `( )   [ ] ` associate left to right and have higher precedence than `*` so read `int* arr[8]` as an array of size 8 where each element points to an int and `int (*arr)[8]` as a pointer to an array of size 8 that holds integers

Comment: Perhaps this is no relevant, but aren't pointers supposed to be 8 bytes?
I assume 9 years ago they were usually 4 bytes, but now they are usually 8 with exception to older x32 bit processors and x86 bit compilation mode. Some implementation may even say pointers are 12 bytes.

Answer (score 277):

Use the [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) program, as suggested by K&R.

```
$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain int* arr1[8];
declare arr1 as array 8 of pointer to int
cdecl> explain int (*arr2)[8]
declare arr2 as pointer to array 8 of int
cdecl> explain int *(arr3[8])
declare arr3 as array 8 of pointer to int
cdecl>
```

It works the other way too.

```
cdecl> declare x as pointer to function(void) returning pointer to float
float *(*x)(void )
```

Comment: @ankii Most Linux distributions should have a package.  You could also build your own binary.

Comment: ah sorry for not mentioning, macOS here. will see if available, otherwise website is fine too. ^^ thanks for letting me know about this.. Feel free to flag NLN .

Comment: @ankii You can install from Homebrew (and maybe MacPorts?).  If those are not to your taste, it is trivial to build your own from the Github link on the top right of cdecl.org (I just built it on macOS Mojave). Then just copy the cdecl binary to your PATH.  I recommend $PATH/bin, because there is no need to involve root in something as simple as this.

Comment: Oh hadn't read the little paragraph about installation in readme. just some commands and flags for handling dependencies..  Installed using brew. :)

Answer (score 133):

I don't know if it has an official name, but I call it the Right-Left Thingy(TM).

Start at the variable, then go right, and left, and right...and so on.

```
int* arr1[8];
```

*`arr1` is an array of 8 pointers to integers.*

```
int (*arr2)[8];
```

*`arr2` is a pointer (the parenthesis block the right-left) to an array of 8 integers.*

```
int *(arr3[8]);
```

*`arr3` is an array of 8 pointers to integers.*

This should help you out with complex declarations.

Comment: I have heard it referred to by the name of "The Spiral Rule", which can be found [here](http://www.c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: @InkBlend: The spiral rule is different from [right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html). The [former fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rule-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error) in cases like `int *a[][10]` while the latter succeeds.

Comment: As InkBlend and legends2k said, this is Spiral Rule which is more complex and doesn't work in all cases, so there is no reason to use it.

Comment: Don't forget the lef to right associativity of `( ) [ ]` and right to left of `* &`

Comment: @legends2k : What is the declaration readout for int *a[][10]

Comment: For the declarations ( int *a[][10];) will "a" be treated as a two dimensional array of pointer to integers or "a" will be an array of pointers to array of integers of size 10.

Comment: Above link unreachable; [Right-Left rule](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/7042/%2fArticles%2f7042%2fHow-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations#right_left_rule). @beastboy It'd be "_`a` is an array of unknown length of array of 10 pointers to `int`_" i.e. the former in your question.

Answer (score 28):

```
int *a[4]; // Array of 4 pointers to int

int (*a)[4]; //a is a pointer to an integer array of size 4

int (*a[8])[5]; //a is an array of pointers to integer array of size 5
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 3rd one be: a is an array of pointers to integer array of size 8 ? I mean each of the integer arrays will be of size 8 right?

Comment: @Rushil: no, the last subscript (`[5]`) represents the inner dimension. This means that `(*a[8])` is the first dimension, and is thus the outer representation of the array. What each element within `a` **points to** is a different integer array of size 5.

Comment: Thanks for the third one. I'm looking for how to write array of pointers to array.

Answer (score 16):

The answer for the last two can also be deducted from the golden rule in C:

> Declaration follows use.

`int (*arr2)[8];`

What happens if you dereference `arr2`? You get an array of 8 integers.

`int *(arr3[8]);`

What happens if you take an element from `arr3`? You get a pointer to an integer.

This also helps when dealing with pointers to functions. To take sigjuice's example:

`float *(*x)(void )`

What happens when you dereference `x`? You get a function that you can call with no arguments. What happens when you call it? It will return a pointer to a `float`.

Operator precedence is always tricky, though. However, using parentheses can actually also be confusing because declaration follows use. At least, to me, intuitively `arr2` looks like an array of 8 pointers to ints, but it is actually the other way around. Just takes some getting used to. Reason enough to always add a comment to these declarations, if you ask me :)

**edit: example**

By the way, I just stumbled across the following situation: a function that has a static matrix and that uses pointer arithmetic to see if the row pointer is out of bounds. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ELEM(ar) (sizeof(ar) / sizeof((ar)[0]))

int *
put_off(const int newrow[2])
{
    static int mymatrix[3][2];
    static int (*rowp)[2] = mymatrix;
    int (* const border)[] = mymatrix + NUM_ELEM(mymatrix);

    memcpy(rowp, newrow, sizeof(*rowp));
    rowp += 1;
    if (rowp == border) {
        rowp = mymatrix;
    }

    return *rowp;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int row[2] = {0, 1};
    int *rout;

    for (i = 0; i &lt; 6; i++) {
        row[0] = i;
        row[1] += i;
        rout = put_off(row);
        printf("%d (%p): [%d, %d]\n", i, (void *) rout, rout[0], rout[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 (0x804a02c): [0, 0]
1 (0x804a034): [0, 0]
2 (0x804a024): [0, 1]
3 (0x804a02c): [1, 2]
4 (0x804a034): [2, 4]
5 (0x804a024): [3, 7]
```

Note that the value of border never changes, so the compiler can optimize that away. This is different from what you might initially want to use: `const int (*border)[3]`: that declares border as a pointer to an array of 3 integers that will not change value as long as the variable exists. However, that pointer may be pointed to any other such array at any time. We want that kind of behaviour for the argument, instead (because this function does not change any of those integers). Declaration follows use.

(p.s.: feel free to improve this sample!)

Answer (score 5):

```
typedef int (*PointerToIntArray)[];
typedef int *ArrayOfIntPointers[];
```

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, right unary operators (like `[]`, `()`, etc) take preference over left ones.  So, `int *(*ptr)()[];` would be a pointer that points to a function that returns an array of pointers to int (get the right operators as soon as you can as you get out of the parenthesis)

Comment: That is true, but it is also ilegal.  You can not have a function that returns an array.  I tried and got this: `error: ‘foo’ declared as function returning an array
 int foo(int arr_2[5][5])[5];` under GCC 8 with `$ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors test.c`

Comment: The reason of the compiler to give that error is that it is interpreting the function as returning an array, as the correct interpretation of the precedence rule states.  It is ilegal as a declaration, but the legal declaration `int *(*ptr)();` allows an expression like `p()[3]` (or `(*p)()[3]`) to be used later.

Comment: Ok, if I understand it, you are talking about creating a function that returns a pointer to the first element of an array (not an array itself), and later use that function as if it were returning an array?  Interesting idea. I'll try it.
`int *foo(int arr_2[5][5]) {
    return  &(arr_2[2][0]);
}` and call it like this: `foo(arr)[4];` which should contain `arr[2][4]`, right?

Comment: right... but you were right also, and the declaration was ilegal. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use the simple rule ..

```
example int * (*ptr)()[];
start from ptr
```

" `ptr` is a pointer to " 
go towards right ..its ")" now go left its a "("
come out go right  "()" so
" to a function which takes no arguments " go left "and returns a pointer " go right "to 
an array" go left " of integers "

Comment: I would improve that a little bit: "ptr is a name that refers to" go right... it's `)`, now go left... it's `*` "a pointer to" go right... it's `)`, now go left... it's a `(` come out, go right `()` so " to a function which takes no arguments " go right... `[]` "and returns an array of" go right `;` end, so go left... `*` "pointers to" go left... `int` "integers"

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I interpret it:

```
int *something[n];
```

> Note on precedence: array subscript operator (`[]`) has higher priority than
>   dereference operator (`*`).

So, here we will apply the `[]` before `*`, making the statement equivalent to:

```
int *(something[i]);
```

> Note on how a declaration makes sense: `int num` means *`num` is an `int`*, `int *ptr` or `int (*ptr)` means, (value at `ptr`) is
>   an `int`, which makes `ptr` a pointer to `int`.

This can be read as, (value of the (value at ith index of the something)) is an integer. So, (value at the ith index of something) is an (integer pointer), which makes the something an array of integer pointers.

In the second one,

```
int (*something)[n];
```

To make sense out of this statement, you must be familiar with this fact:

> Note on pointer representation of array: `somethingElse[i]` is equivalent to `*(somethingElse + i)`

So, replacing `somethingElse` with `(*something)`, we get `*(*something + i)`, which is an integer as per declaration. So, `(*something)` given us an array, which makes something equivalent to *(pointer to an array)*.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the second declaration is confusing to many. Here's an easy way to understand it.

Lets have an array of integers, i.e. `int B[8]`.

Let's also have a variable A which points to B. Now, value at A is B, i.e. `(*A) == B`. Hence A points to an array of integers. In your question, arr is similar to A.

Similarly, in `int* (*C) [8]`, C is a pointer to an array of pointers to integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *arr1[5]
```

In this declaration, `arr1` is an array of 5 pointers to integers.
Reason: Square brackets have higher precedence over * (dereferncing operator).
And in this type, number of rows are fixed (5 here), but number of columns is variable.

```
int (*arr2)[5]
```

In this declaration, `arr2` is a pointer to an integer array of 5 elements.
Reason: Here, () brackets have higher precedence than []. 
And in this type, number of rows is variable, but the number of columns is fixed (5 here).

Answer (score -9):

In pointer to an integer if pointer is incremented then it goes next integer.

in array of pointer if pointer is incremented it jumps to next array

Comment: "*in array of pointer if pointer is incremented it jumps to next array*" this is plain wrong.