# What does this mean const int*& var?

Tags: c++

I saw someone using this in one answer:

```
void methodA(const int*& var);
```

I couldn't understand what the argument means.

AFAIK:

- `const int var` => `const int` value which can't be changed
- `const int* var` => pointer to `const int`, ie `*var` can't be changed but `var` can be changed
- `const int& var` => reference to `const int`, ie value of `var` can't be changed

What does `const int*& var` mean? Is `const int& *var` also possible?

Can you please give some example as well, like what can and can't be done with it?

**UPDATE**:

I am not sure if I am thinking the right way, but I began to think of a reference as an alias of the variable that was passed as argument, so:

`const int * p;`

`methodA(p)` => here we are passing `p` as `const int *` but we don't know if this is pass by value or what, until we see the definition of `methodA`, so if `methodA` is like this:

`methodA(const int * & p2)` ==> here `p2` is another name to `p`, ie `p` and `p2` are the same from now on

`methodA(const int* p2)` ==> here `p2` is passed as value, ie `p2` is just local to this method

Please correct me if I am thinking the wrong way. If yes, I might need to study some more about this. Can you please point to some nice references?

**UPDATE 2**:

If some beginner like me wants to know more about this thing, you can use the **c++decl** / **cdecl** program from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation/859676#859676), which I just discovered to be very useful.

```
$ c++decl
Type `help' or `?' for help
c++decl> explain const int&* p
declare p as pointer to reference to const int
c++decl> explain const int*& p
declare p as reference to pointer to const int
```

But, as every one here pointed out, the first example isn't legal in C++.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is a reference to a pointer to an int that is const.

There is another post somewhat related, actually, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation/859676#859676). My answer gives a sorta of general algorithm to figuring these things out.

This: `const int& *var` has no meaning, because you cannot have a pointer to reference.

If the const's and pointers are getting in the way, remember you can typedef these things:

```
typedef int* IntPointer;
typedef const IntPointer ConstIntPointer;

void foo(ConstIntPointer&); // pass by reference
void bar(const ConstIntPointer&); // pass by const reference
void baz(ConstIntPointer); // pass by value
```

Might make it easier to read.

---

If you need more help on C++, [read this](https://isocpp.org/faq/). More specifically, [references](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references).

References as variables do *not* take space:

```
int i; // takes sizeof(int)
int*pi = &i; // takes sizeof(int*)

int& ri = i; // takes no space.
             // any operations done to ri
             // are simply done to i
```

References as parameters use pointers to achieve the end effect:

```
void foo(int& i)
{
    i = 12;
}

void foo_transformed(int *i)
{
    *i = 12;
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    foo(i); // same as:
    foo_transformed(&i); // to the compiler (only sort of)
}
```

So it's actually passing the address of `i` on the stack, so takes `sizeof(int*)` space on the stack. But don't start thinking about references as pointers. They are *not* the same.

Comment: in third method baz, ConstIntPointer == const int * var, how is this pass by value, there is pointer involved ?? I am confused now.

Comment: Pointers take space themselves. Pointers are variables that store the address of another variable. It's going to copy that value, push it on the stack, and call that function.

Comment: You are passing the value that is stored in the pointer (i.e. the memory address).

Comment: The 3rd one is passing the pointer by value, whereas the previous two is passing the pointer by reference. We are talking about the passing the pointer here, not concerning ourself with that the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: In the C++ spec., it is unspecified whether references take space.

Comment: @IanMallett: This is true, I was talking about the practical aspects.

Comment: "References as variables do _not_ take space" <- not necessarily.

Comment: @IanMallett: Yes, I *just* said in the comment above that at the time of writing this old answer I was talking about it's implementation in practice. You're not giving me any new information.

Answer (score 10):

Some folks find it easier reading this from right to left.  So

> const int*&

is a reference to a pointer to an integer that is const.

As you know, references cannot be changed, only what they refer to can be changed.  So the reference will refer to just one pointer to an integer that is const.  Since the pointer is not const - the integer is const - you can change the pointer to point to a different integer.

Compare this to

> int* const &

This is a reference to a constant pointer to an integer.  Again the reference is immutable, and in this case it is a reference to a constant pointer.  What you can change in this case is the integer value since there was no const either side of the int keyword.

Just to add confusion, const int and int const are the same.  However int const * and int * const are very different.  The first is a pointer to a constant integer, so the pointer is mutable.  The second is a constant pointer to an integer, so the integer is mutable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

It is a reference to a const pointer, i.e. a pointer where you cannot modify the data pointed to. As the reference is used as an argument to a method the method is able to modify the pointer to let it point to something else (still something that cannot be modified).

With regards to your update:

> so if methodA is like this methodA(const int * & p2) ==> here p2 is another name to p, i.e. p and p2 are same from now on and if methodA(const int* p2) ==> here p2 is passed as value i.e p2 is just local to this method

Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `var` is a refernce to a pointer to const char.

Since it's a reference, a change to the parameter inside `methodA()` will be reflected in the argument that is passed to `methodA()`:

```
void methodA( const char*& var)
{
    static const char newdata[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};

    printf( "var points to %s\n", var);

    var = newdata;
}


int main()
{
    const char * p = "123";

    printf( "p points to: %s\n", p);      // prints "p points to: 123"
    methodA( p);
    printf( "now p points to: %s\n", p);  // prints "now p points to: abc"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example, a getter that returns the address of a private data item.  The item happens to be an int for simplicity.  A large array of items would be a more practical case (a zero-copy getter).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
  void getter(const int *&data) const
  {
      data = &val;
  }
private:
  int val = 5;
};

main()
{
    X obj;
    const int *data;

    obj.getter(data);
    cout << data << endl;
    cout << *data << endl;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).