# What does this macro define?

Tags: c, macros

I read this piece of macro(C code) and was confused in decoding it to know what it defines. What does it define?

```
#define sram (*((unsigned char (*)[1]) 0))
```

-AD

Comment: Hard to tell. Can you provide an example of how it's used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think `sram` means "start of RAM".

---

```
unsigned char[1]
```

An array of size 1 of unsigned chars.

```
unsigned char(*)[1]
```

A [pointer to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation) of size 1 of unsigned chars.

```
(unsigned char (*)[1]) 0
```

Cast 0 to a pointer to an array of size 1 of unsigned chars.

```
*((unsigned char (*)[1]) 0)
```

Read some memory at location 0, and interpret the result as an array of size 1 of unsigned chars.

```
(*((unsigned char (*)[1]) 0))
```

Just to [avoid 1+5*8+1==42](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%80%81%E5%AE%87%E5%AE%99%E3%80%81%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E7%AD%94%E3%81%88#.E6.BC.94.E7.AE.97.E9.A0.86.E5.BA.8F.E3.81.AE.E3.83.90.E3.82.B0.3F).

```
#define sram (*((unsigned char (*)[1]) 0))
```

Define the variable `sram` to the memory starting at location 0, and interpret the result as an array of size 1 of unsigned chars.

Comment: +1 for providing me with an explanation to that conundrum in the Hitchhiker's Guide five-part trilogy. Oh, and I guess the rest of your answer was okay too.

Comment: Or on an embedded system it could just mean "SRAM" (Static Random Access Memory) which is typically what a microcontroller's on-chip RAM is made of.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it's returning the base address (0) of memory (RAM) :)

Answer (score 1):

It defines "sram" as a pointer to memory starting at zero. You can access memory via the pointer, e.g. sram[0] is address zero, sram[1] is the stuff at address one, etc.

Specifically it is casting 0 to be a pointer to an array of unsigned char and going indirect through that (leaving an array of unsigned char).

A similar result can be obtained by

```
#define sram ((unsigned char*)0)
```

It is also completely undefined in standard C, but that doesn't stop people from using it and having angels fly out of their navels.