# Which of * and [] bind strongest in C?

Tags: c, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

In C, is `int *thing[5]` an array of five pointers, each pointing to an integer, or a pointer to an array of five integers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[]` trumps `*` per the [C precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) which means you have an array of five int pointers.

Answer (score 6):

If in doubt use parenthesis - the maintenance programmers will thank you (as will you at 5am when you finally find the bug!)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe is a duplicate... It is an array of five pointers to integer; the program `cdecl` cited in a similar question can be useful for newbie:

```
cdecl> explain int *t[5];
declare t as array 5 of pointer to int
```

Comment: Also:

    `cdecl> explain int (* thing)[5]
    -->
    declare thing as pointer to array 5 of int`

This gives the pointer to an array of 5 ints he asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Absent any explicit grouping with parentheses, both the array subscript operator `[]` and function call operator `()` bind before `*`, so

```
T *a[N];        -- a is an N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];      -- a is a pointer to an N-element array of T

T *f();         -- f is a function returning pointer to T
T (*f)();       -- f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

This follows from the grammar (taken from Harbison & Steele, 5th ed., appendix B):

```
declarator:
  pointer-declarator
  direct-declarator

pointer-declarator:
  pointer direct-declarator

pointer:
  * type-qualifier-listopt
  * type-qualifier-listopt pointer

direct-declarator:
  simple-declarator
  ( declarator )
  function-declarator
  array-declarator

function-declarator:
  direct-declarator ( parameter-type-list )
  direct-declarator ( identifier-listopt )

array-declarator:
  direct-declarator [ constant-expressionopt ]
  direct-declarator [ array-qualifier-listopt array-size-expressionopt ] 
  direct-declarator [ array-qualifier-listopt * ]
```