# Operator precedence in C Definitions

Tags: c, definition, operator-precedence

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) claims that the `[]` operator precedes the `*` operator in evaluation.

Then, why does the following statement:

```
char *a[3];
```

declare an array of 3 character pointers, rather than a pointer to an array of 3 characters as per the operator precedence?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation Specifically see the answer regarding `cdecl`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because, as Wikipedia says, `[]` has higher precedence than `*`?

Processing the declaration, the `a[3]` is processed as 'array of 3' before you process the `*`.

To declare a pointer to an array of three characters, you have to use parentheses to override the default precedence:

```
char (*a)[3];
```

Now the parentheses take precedence over the array.

Comment: But don't declarations have separate interpretation rules as claimed in other answers?

Comment: @crypto, the whole point of declaration syntax in C is that "declaration mimicks use".

Comment: @crypto: No, not really.  As @AProgrammer says, the design of the C declaration system is such that declaration mimics use.  So, `a[0]` is a `char *`, and `*a[0]` is a `char`.

Comment: @crypto: See my answer below.  Yes, there are different production rules for declarations, but they follow the same precedence rules as expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the grammar for a declarator as taken from the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (§ 6.7.5):

```
declarator:
    pointeropt direct-declarator

direct-declarator:
    identifier
    ( declarator )
    direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expressionopt ]
    direct-declarator [ static type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expression ]
    direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-list static assignment-expression ]
    direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-listopt * ]
    direct-declarator ( parameter-type-list )
    direct-declarator ( identifier-listopt )

pointer:
    * type-qualifier-listopt
    * type-qualifier-listopt pointer

type-qualifier-list:
    type-qualifier
    type-qualifier-list type-qualifier

parameter-type-list:
    parameter-list
    parameter-list , ...

parameter-list:
    parameter-declaration
    parameter-list , parameter-declaration

parameter-declaration:
    declaration-specifiers declarator
    declaration-specifiers abstract-declaratoropt

identifier-list:
    identifier
    identifier-list , identifier
```

As you can see, both `[]` and `()` bind to the declarator before `*`.  Take the declaration

```
int *a[N];
```

The declarator is `*a[N]`, which fits the *pointer<sub>opt</sub> direct-declarator* pattern above, and is thus parsed as `*(a[N])`, so `a` is an N-element array of pointer.

To sum up:

```
T *a[N]      -- declares an N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N]    -- declares a pointer to an N-element array of T
T *f()       -- declares a function returning pointer to T
T (*f)()     -- declares a pointer to a function returning T
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused about the question - the interpretation of the declaration matches the operator precedence.  If you want a pointer to an an array you have to use parens to 'bind the `*` to the indentifier' before the `[]` binding.

```
char (*a)[3];
```