# C compound literals, pointer to arrays

Tags: c, compound-literals

I'm trying to assign a compound literal to a variable, but it seems not to work, see:

```
  int *p[] = (int *[]) {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

I got a error in gcc.

but if I write only this:

```
  int p[] = (int []) {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Then it's okay.

But is not what I want.

I don't understand why the error occurrs, because if I initialize it like a array, or use it with a pointer of arrays of chars, its okay, see:

```
  int *p[] = (int *[]) {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; //I got a error
  int p[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; //it's okay
  char *p[] = (char *[]) {"one", "two"...}; // it's okay!
```

Note I don't understand why I got an error in the first one, and please I can't, or I don't want to write like the second form because it's needs to be a compound literals, and I don't want to say how big is the array to the compiler. I want something like the second one, but for int values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to initialize these arrays in one statement?

Comment: If I understood the question, it simplify things, I can swap va_args to compound literals for example...

Comment: You state several times that you get an error, yet never tell us what the error is.  Have you learned nothing, Padawan?

Comment: `int p[] = (int []) {1,2,3,4,5,6};` gives some error with gcc 4.8.2 on Linux. The error is 'array initialized from non-constant array expression'. What's your gcc version?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, the casts are redundant in all of your examples and can be removed. Secondly, you are using the syntax for initializing a multidimensional array, and that requires the second dimension the be defined in order to allocate a sequential block of memory. Instead, try one of the two approaches below:

- Multidimensional array:

  ```
  int p[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
  ```
- Array of pointers to one dimensional arrays:

  ```
  int p1[] = {1,2,3};
  int p2[] = {4,5,6};
  int *p[] = {p1,p2};
  ```

The latter method has the advantage of allowing for sub-arrays of varying length. Whereas, the former method ensures that the memory is laid out contiguously.

Another approach that I highly recommend that you do NOT use is to encode the integers in string literals. This is a non-portable hack. Also, the data in string literals is supposed to be constant. Do your arrays need to be mutable?

```
int *p[] = (int *[]) {
    "\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00",
    "\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00"
};
```

That example might work on a 32-bit little-endian machine, but I'm typing this from an iPad and cannot verify it at the moment. Again, please don't use that; I feel dirty for even bringing it up.

The casting method you discovered also appears to work with a pointer to a pointer. That can be indexed like a multidimensional array as well.

```
int **p = (int *[]) { (int[]) {1,2,3}, (int[]) {4,5,6} };
```

Comment: Yes, it's redundant in my example, but it's would good for a function parameter, and how can I avoid the dimension with pointer? like the second example... thanks for your answer.

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker - you have to tell C the last array size, since the C will not try and guess on its own. It is important for pointer arithmetics etc.

Comment: Thanks guy, Are there some way to write the your first example like the last one? Because I can't say to compiler how big is my array, and it needs to be a array inside another....I begin to think that it is not possible...Thanks anyway.

Comment: You could encode the integers in string literals, but that would not be portable.

Comment: Hi, this hack is nicer, see, I found an approach to get what I want... If I write this in this way :   int **p = (int *[]) {{1,2,3},(int []){4,5,6}}; it works, it will help me a lot, but see, writing (int []) in every array is no so perfect because I will need to use macros to obfuscate it...maybe another solution for my problem?

Comment: The correct is : int **p = (int *[]) {(int []){1,2,3},(int []){4,5,6}};

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work. It is definitely better than using string literals.

Comment: the type in `()` is not a cast -- it is a part of the compound literal syntax.

Comment: @u0b34a0f6ae Yes. That's what I was thinking too. I didn't trust myself atm because I'm so dead tired but I thought this cannot possibly be correct what the answer started out as. It's not a cast but indeed part of the compound literal syntax. Thanks for confirming this. Actually if I wasn't so tired I would say that this answer has the wrong idea (at least for the first part).

Comment: On second thought: it must be that the answer is trying to show the differences. Still your point is valid. But to Judge: compound literals isn't casting. As the other commentator points out the () is part of the compound literal syntax.

Answer (score 13):

First understand that **"Arrays are not pointers".**

```
int p[] = (int []) {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

In the above case `p` is an array of integers. Copying the elements `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` to `p`. Typecasting is not necessary here and both the `rvalue` and `lvalue` types match which is an integer array and so no error.

```
int *p[] = (int *[]) {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

> "Note I don't understand why I got a error in the first one,.."

In the above case, `p` an array of integer pointers. But the `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}` is a two dimensional array ( i.e., [][] ) and cannot be type casted to array of pointers. You need to initialize as -

```
int p[][3] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6} };
  // ^^ First index of array is optional because with each column having 3 elements
  // it is obvious that array has two rows which compiler can figure out.
```

**But why did this statement compile ?**

```
char *p[] = {"one", "two"...};
```

String literals are different from integer literals. In this case also, `p` is an array of character pointers. When actually said `"one"`, **it can either be copied to an array or point to its location considering it as read only**.

```
char cpy[] = "one" ;
cpy[0] = 't' ;  // Not a problem

char *readOnly = "one" ;
readOnly[0] = 't' ;  // Error because of copy of it is not made but pointing
                     // to a read only location.
```

With string literals, either of the above case is possible. So, that is the reason the statement compiled. But -

```
char *p[] = {"one", "two"...}; // All the string literals are stored in 
                               // read only locations and at each of the array index 
                               // stores the starting index of each string literal.
```

> I don't want to say how big is the array to the compiler.

Dynamically allocating the memory using `malloc` is the solution.

Hope it helps !

Comment: You said that {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}} is a two dimensional array , and cannot be type casted to array of ponters, but I learned that any array is a pointer, and it is passed like a pointer to functions, thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: If array is a pointer, then try this - `void foo( int **twoDimensionalArray){}` and try to pass `p` as mentioned in your example which have the okey comment.

Comment: Just because it is possible for a 1D array doesn't mean that **array is a pointer**.

Comment: Sorry but I can't say how big is it to compiler, much less use malloc, the perfect approach is to use pointer instead, I found a solution writing : int **p = (int *[]) {(int []){1,2,3},(int []){4,5,6}}; but I need to cast to every array inside the main array, I'm finding a solution to do without it.

Comment: There are subtle differences between arrays and pointer, but I don't think it will matter in your case other than I itialization options.

Comment: One of differences is that you can't change the address of array, but you can do that for pointer. For that reason you can call array `static address` and pointer - `dynamic address`.

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker No. As Judge says there are differences. Whereas `int *p;` isn't allocated `int a[4];` is: `a[0] = 1;` is perfectly safe but `p[1] = 1` (or `*(p+1)`) is not. I hope I typed that wrong (can barely see atm!). Now passing `a` to a function it will act as a pointer to the first element but that's not the same thing. There are other ways this shows itself.

Answer (score 5):

Since nobody's said it: If you want to have a pointer-to-2D-array, you can (probably) do something like

```
int (*p)[][3] = &(int[][3]) {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

**EDIT:** Or you can have a pointer to its first element via

```
int (*p)[3] = (int[][3]) {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

The reason why your example doesn't work is because `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}` is not a valid initializer for type `int*[]` (because `{1,2,3}` is not a valid initializer for `int*`). Note that it is **not** an `int[2][3]` — it's simply an invalid expression.

The reason why it works for strings is because `"one"` is a valid initializer for `char[]` and `char[N]` (for some N>3). As an *expression*, it's *approximately* equivalent to `(const char[]){'o','n','e','\0'}` except the compiler doesn't complain too much when it loses constness.

And yes, there's a big difference between an initializer and an expression. I'm pretty sure `char s[] = (char[]){3,2,1,0};` is a compile error in C99 (and possibly C++ pre-0x). There are loads of other things too, but `T foo = ...;` is variable initialization, not assignment, even though they look similar. (They are especially different in C++, since the assignment operator is not called.)

And the reason for the confusion with pointers:

- Type `T[]` is implicitly converted to type `T*` (a pointer to its first element) when necessary.
- `T arg1[]` in a function argument list actually means `T * arg1`. You cannot pass an array to a function for Various Reasons. It is not possible. If you try, you are actually passing a pointer-to-array. (You can, however, pass a struct containing a fixed-size array to a function.)
- They both can be dereferenced and subscripted with identical (I think) semantics.

**EDIT:** The observant might notice that my first example is roughly syntactically equivalent to `int * p = &1;`, which is invalid. This works in C99 because a compound literal inside a function "has automatic storage duration associated with the enclosing block" ([ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)).

Comment: Could you add some example where T[] is implicitly cvonverted to T(*)[]? You explanation is thorough! I think your anwer really see through the mist of compound literal and points out the true problem!

Comment: After some test, I think it should be `int (*p)[3] = (int[][3]) {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};`

Answer (score 1):

The one that you are using is array of int pointers. You should use pointer to array :

```
int (*p)[] = (int *) {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation) answer for more details.

Comment: I don't think that even compiles.

Comment: @tc Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation and you should try it first before commenting.

Comment: I'm still pretty sure it does not compile.

Comment: Here is the code: #include <stdio.h>  void main() {  int (*p)[] = (int *) {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}; }

Comment: I was wrong; it appears to compile, but is equivalent to `int (*p)[] = (int*)1;` ("braces around scalar initializer", "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast", "excess elements in scalar initializer", "initialization from incompatible pointer type", "return type from 'main' is not 'int'"). I stand by my downvote.

Comment: @Karan Maybe. But your example is undefined. In other words the compiler is free to do whatever it wants even if that's halt and catch fire (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire_(computing) ). `main()` must return an int. This is not negotiable. Even if it appears to work with your compiler it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confusing pointers and array. They're not the same thing! An array is the list itself, while a pointer is just an address. Then, with pointer arithmetic you can pretend pointers are array, and with the fact that the name of an array is a pointer to the first element everything sums up in a mess. ;)

```
int *p[] = (int *[]) {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};      //I got a error
```

Here, p is an array of pointers, so you are trying to assign the elements whose addresses are 1, 2, 3 to the first array and 4, 5, 6 to the second array. The seg fault happens because you can't access those memory locations.

```
int p[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};              //it's okay
```

This is ok because this is an array of arrays, so this time 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 aren't addresses but the *elements* themselves.

```
char *p[] = (char *[]) {"one", "two"...};    // it's okay!
```

This is ok because the string literals ("one", "two", ...) aren't really strings but pointers to those strings, so you're assigning to p[1] the address of the string literal "one".
BTW, this is the same as doing `char abc[]; abc = "abc";`. This won't compile, because you can't assign a pointer to an array, while `char *def; def = "def";` solves the problem.

Comment: Um, `char abc[] = "abc";` compiles just fine -- string literals are valid initializers for char arrays.