# C++ Array Inquiry

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why can we do:

```
char* array = "String";
```

but not

```
int* array = 1;
```

To my understanding * means address, so I don't really understand why we can give a non-address value, like "String." to char* array.

Comment: * doesn't mean address. Look up pointers in your book.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. It points to a memory address, hence why we can do code like:

int a = 1;
int* pointer = &a.

&a is the address, and pointer points to that address.

I misworded the question, so apologies for that, but I am still left confused about why char* array can accept a value that is not a address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declare and initialize pointer concisely (i. e. pointer to int)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805673/declare-and-initialize-pointer-concisely-i-e-pointer-to-int)

Answer (score 2):

`char* array` means that `array` is a variable that can hold the address of another object (such as another variable or constant).

If the program has `"String"`,  it means that there is actually an array of 7 characters that exists in memory somewhere and it holds the contents `"String"`.

When you write `array = "String";` then the variable `array` is made to hold the address of the letter `'S'` in that string.

This is because C++ has a rule, sometimes called *array-pointer decay* which means that if you try to use an array (such as `"String"`) in a context where a value is expected, then it gets automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of that array.

Without that rule you'd have to write `array = &("String"[0]);`  . The rule was included in C originally to avoid having to write `&....[0]` all over the place when working with arrays, although in hindsight it seems to have generated more pain than pleasure.

Moving onto `int* i = 1`.  You have said that `i` can hold the address of an `int`, but you have not provided any such address.  Variables thare aren't arrays *don't* automatically get converted to their address.  In fact `1` isn't even a variable. We call it a *prvalue* , it doesn't have any memory storage area associated with it, so it does not have an address.  To point at an instance of a `1` you would have to make a variable, for example:

```
int j = 1; int* i = &j;
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` does not mean adress. Its meaning is context sensitive, but most of the time it means pointer.

The reason for this, not to work is because `"String"` is an array of characters, or a pointer to an character. In contrast to this, 1 is a literal which is not a valid adress. You should write `int array = 1` instead, and after that you could do `int *brray = &array`.

Comment: Got it, so can you just verify whether I have this right now?

a int is a literal, a string is a pointer to the address of the first character in what is basically a char array.

Comment: @user2814533 A string literal has slightly unusual behavior in C/C++, but yes, if you use it as a pointer, it's a pointer to an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I don't really understand why we can give a non-address value, like `"String."` "*

That's because a character string literal actually is `const char[]` array, which decays to a pointer when assigned to a `char*`, while `1` isn't one and you can't take it's address in any way.

Comment: No it isn't. The type of a string literal is `const char[N]`. It's not an address.

Answer (score 0):

`*` means a pointer, not an address. You can retrieve an address using the `&` operator.

```
char* array = "String";
```

Actually declares `array` as a pointer to a character, and the `=` sign after the declaration tells the compiler what value should the pointer posses. In this case it's an address of `"String"` in the string pool somewhere in the memory of the run program.

```
int* array = 1;
```

Doesn't put the address of `1` to `array` as you may expect. However, with a little adjustment

```
int* array = (int*)1;
```

... it could point to an integer at address `1`, which is unfortunately unaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

This assignment:
 `char* array = "String";`
Assign "String" to an available location in memory and returns the memory address of the first position of "String" in memory. "array" stores the address of "S".

This assignment:
`int* array = 1;`
Doesn't work because you are trying to assign an integer to a pointer to integer. The types are different