# Create pointer to value in one line

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, static-memory-allocation

I would like to create a pointer to a value in one line; I want the same functionality as this:

```
int i = MY_VALUE
int * j = &i;
```

However, I want to do this in one line, and do not want to use two variables.  I know that I can do this:

```
int * i = new int (MY_VALUE);
```

But I don't want to use dynamic memory; I want to use static memory.

Is there a way that I can allocate a pointer to a value, statically, with one variable, in one line?

Comment: Is there really a surge or random questions in C++ today, or is it just me?

Comment: Is this question about C or C++ ? There's a duplicate for C [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805673/declare-and-initialize-pointer-concisely-i-e-pointer-to-int).

Comment: Can you explain why you need it to be on one line and without using two variables? That might help us come up with an acceptable solution...

Comment: @Quentin It's about C++, but I thought that the answers might be the same for both languages.

Comment: @Brian Of course, if it's not possible to do what I want to do, I can use two variables.  I wanted to do it with one variable because of the potential overhead of two variables when there could be one.

Comment: You should really add more context, because I doubt there is anything to be gained from having only one variable. In fact, since that one variable would be the pointer, there **has** to be an actual variable somewhere for it to point to, even if it is not named in the code.

Comment: I removed the C flag, it is really too different from C++ in these points to be relevant, here. Also, you are asking about "static" memory, this seems to point to a confusion what static means.

Comment: OP: One thing to think about is that a pointer is like a street address to a house. No matter how you (legally) declare it, if you have an "address", you will (should) have a "house" in memory [otherwise you get UB]. In other words, for all intents and purposes, you will have two "variables" in memory. 

Also, @SergeyA, it's not just you. The main reason for the surge is that we're a few weeks into a new college quarter.

Comment: @JasonMc92, thanks for info and confirming I am not seeing things :)

Answer (score 4):

If you must...

```
int i = 5, *p = &i;
```

Comment: Just saying, though it's one line, not one variable, anyway.. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes I've just re-read the question... And lost interest in answering it. :/

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot have a *pointer to a value*, you can only have a *pointer to a variable* or *pointer to an object (lvalue)*.

To elaborate, from C prespective, quoting `C11` chapter §6.5.3.2 for the usage of `&` operator

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
>   `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
>   not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

So, something along the line of

```
int * p = &10;
```

is purely invalid.

Comment: C++14 actually has the wording revised. But you still can't take a pointer to value, of course.

Comment: @SergeyA The last part you mentioned is what I tried to highlight. :)