# Why does int* ptr_arr_int = {1,2}; not work in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Why does `int* ptr_arr_int = {1,2};` gives a compiler error, but whereas `char* ptr_arr_char = "amruth";` compiles fine?

```
int* ptr_arr_int = {1,2};         // ->ERROR
char* ptr_arr_char = "amruth";    // ->OK
```

Comment: Those aren't equivalent. `char* ptr_arr_char2 = {'a', 'b'};` won't work either.

Comment: @Blaze , what is the equivalent char* ptr_arr_char = "amruth";  for integer ?

Comment: Note that you're trying the wrong thing because initialization in C++ sucks, not because of any intellectual restrictions - just in case you were wondering ;)

Comment: @AmruthA there is none.

Comment: Near duplicate for C: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24805673/3233393

Comment: I wouldn't recommend c/c++, it's just undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simply because the language syntax says so. Regarding arrays:

- We must initialize an *array* with a brace-enclosed list `{...}`, containing no more items that what will fit inside the array.
- As a special rule, `char` arrays can be initialized with a string literal, `"..."`.

However, you have no arrays in your code, you only have pointers.

A `char*` can always be set to point at a string literal (in C) so `char* ptr_arr_char = "amruth";` is valid. However, it is fishy style, because the string literal cannot be modified. Correct style is to use `const char*`.

C++ is more strict and string literals in C++ have type `const char[]`. and a C++ compiler will likely give a warning along the lines of "deprecated conversion" if you don't use `const char*`.

As for `int* ptr_arr_int = {1,2};`, it has two problems.

- `{1,2}` is an initializer list, but `ptr_arr_int` is a single item, so it doesn't make any sense. There is a special, odd rule that actually allows us to use `{}` when initializing a single variable, but then you must only have one single initializer inside.
- You cannot initialize a pointer with an integer. See ["Pointer from integer/integer from pointer without a cast" issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186834/pointer-from-integer-integer-from-pointer-without-a-cast-issues).

If you meant to have the pointer point at a temporary array, only existing in the local scope, then you could have used the C feature called *compound literal*:

`int* ptr_arr_int = (int[]){1,2};`

This is AFAIK not possible to do in C++ though, unless you rely on non-standard extensions. But in either language you could of course simply do this instead:

```
int arr[2] = {1,2};
int* ptr_arr_int = arr;
```

Answer (score 12):

`"amruth"` is a `const char[7]` type in C++, and a `char[7]` type in C (although the behaviour on attempting to modify the string is undefined).

This can *decay* to a `const char*` or `char*` type respectively in some circumstances, such as yours.

Although an `int[2]` will similarly decay to an `int*` in some circumstances, `{1, 2}` is neither an `int[2]` nor a `const int[2]` type; rather it is a *brace-initialiser*.

Comment: An `int[2]` type will decay to `int*` quite happily, but `{1,2}` by itself isn't `int[2]`. It's just a brace initializer. With the right context  it could well be initializing e.g., `float[5]`.

Comment: @PSkocik: Yes, I wasn't happy with my last paragraph either.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning C compound literals which are perfectly capable of spawning an object just like string literals do, but don't exist in C++. Another instance of a dual-language questions getting thorny.

Answer (score 7):

As said, the string is an `const char[7]` array and while that can decay to a `char*`, `{1, 2}` cannot decay to `int*` (it's an brace initializer list, similarly: [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)). But note there is also the array `[]` declaration which allows you to automatically declare arrays. Combine that with the [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) since C++11 and you are able to initialize both via `[]`:

```
int ptr_arr_int[] = { 1,2 }; //OK
char ptr_arr_char[] = "amruth"; //OK
```

Comment: `{1, 2}` itself is not an `std::initializer_list`, but a braced initializer list. These are different things, though they have similar names. See: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5.6

Answer (score 6):

A string by itself already implies a storage class -- it's a `static` (+effectively `const`) `char` array declared using special syntax.

In contrast to that, it's not clear how `{1, 2}` in `int *ptr_arr_int = {1, 2}` should be stored. Should it be `static` or `auto`?

If you want it `auto` when in a local scope or `static` when in file scope, then in C>=99 you can explicitly do `int *ptr_arr_int = &(int[]){1,2}[0];` (the `&[0]` is optional).

You could conceivably make this implicit, but how far would you take this?`int ****x = {1,2};` initialized by creating an array, a pointer to it, a pointer to that etc., could result int quite a bit of code/data and hiding a lot of code/data under a simple construct isn't quite the C way. It would also not be clear when the brace syntax should be initializing the ultimate target basic type or some of the intermediate pointer(s).

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring an array of pointers to `int` (`int*`). But the values you initialize the array with (`1` and `2`) are *not* pointers to integers, they are plain `int`egers.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, because `int *` is not a structure that could be initialized with two values like you did with `= {1,2};`.

You could have initialized it this way:

```
int * ptr_arr_int = nullptr;
```

---

The other way could have been using an object that expects two values for construction:

```
struct Point
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

then you could have written:

```
Point p = {1,2};
```

Answer (score 2):

No... that's not correct... that initialiser is only valid for arrays.  Had you written:

```
int array[] = {1, 2};
```

it would be valid.... but you are trying to initialise a **pointer** variable, so this would be valid (despite of the warning, because `0xf45` is not an address):

```
int *pointer = { 0xf45 };
```

(because you put only a single entry, and it is considered a single value)  but:

```
int *pointer = { 0xf45, 0 };
```

(You will get another warning about `excess elements in scalar initializer`)  This means that for a single variable you tried to use two initializers.  The braces notation was born to be able to initialise arrays, but also is permitted to be used with scalar types.  This means that the two notations:

```
{ 0 }; /* a single value between braces */
```

and

```
0;
```

are equivalent.

The solution to your problem is to do an extra step, declaring an array and then pointing to it from the pointer:

```
int array[] = {1, 2};

int *pointer = array;
```

but think that you can make pointer to point to a different place than the beginning of array, and you cannot array to be magically moved elsewhere.  And `&array` means the address of array `array` while `&pointer` means the address of the pointer variable `pointer`.  `pointer` points to the address of `array`, but `array` is a constant pointer pointing to the address of `array[0]`.

Pointers and arrays are somewhat confusing, but never think they are the same thing.  Just compare `sizeof(char[120])` with `sizeof(char *)` and you'll see.