# Would I have a problem here if len is not initialized?

Tags: c

Would it be a problem if I don't initialize len in this code?

```
int* len;
    if (splitCommand(cmd_buff, commands, len) != 0){
        printError();
    }
```

...

```
int splitCommand(char* line, char** commands, int *len){
char* command = strtok(line, ";");

int i = 0;
while(command != NULL){
    commands[i] = command;
    command = strtok(NULL, ";");
    i++;
} *len = i;
return 0; }
```

I'm getting this error:

> gcc -Wall -Werror -o myshell myshell.c
> myshell.c: In function ‘main’:
> myshell.c:131:13: error: ‘len’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
> 131 |         if (splitCommand(cmd_buff, commands, len) != 0){
> |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
> make: *** [Makefile:7: myshell] Error 1

but I'm not sure why it's a problem

Comment: What do you expect `*len` to do when `len` is uninitialized? You probably meant `int len;`, then passing `&len`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare and initialize pointer concisely (i. e. pointer to int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805673/declare-and-initialize-pointer-concisely-i-e-pointer-to-int)

Comment: `*len = i;` Where will the value end up in memory if you pass uninitialized pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int* len;
```

Here, the contents of `len` are indeterminate, i.e. it doesn't point to anything meaningful. Passing it to `splitCommand()` and then dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

```
len ---> Some strange address that may or may not belong to the address space of your program.
```

If the intent was to allow `splitCommand()` to change the value of `len`, simply change the declaration of `len` to:

```
int len;
```

And then pass it to `splitCommand()` like so:

```
if (splitCommand(cmd_buff, commands, &len) != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a very serious problem.

When you declare `len`, it's uninitialized and doesn't point to anything valid; your compiler told you as much. Then, you're trying to dereference it in `splitCommand()`.