# what does the following c++ code do

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I know its very naive question, but i am not able to understand what the following code does.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#define MAXROW 3
#define MAXCOL 4
int main(){
int (*p)[MAXCOL];
p = (int (*)[MAXCOL])malloc(MAXROW*sizeof(*p));
}
```

Please provide a complete explanation including the type and size of p.

```
It is just for learning purpose. I am not using this code in any real application.
```

Comment: You want `<stdlib.h>` instead of `<malloc.h>` to be "more" Standard :)

Comment: Smells like homework? If yes, please tag accordingly. Also, we are no service site where you can just ask us to do your job.

Comment: @pmg: No, you want `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: Code smells like C, title says C++ (which makes this terrible code), and tags say both. Which is it?

Comment: @Tomalak: right. I should have said ... @Nitin: trying to write multi-language source files is hard. I suggest you stick to one of C or C++

Comment: @Xeo - Its not Homework! also, do you own Stackoverflow?

Comment: The code was wrriten by Dr. P.J. Plauger (google him), and he tagged it as C++ in his book. I was just trying to get hang of it.

Comment: @Nitin: Nobody "owns" Stack Overflow (unless you're talking legally).

Comment: @Nitin: No-one writes code like that in a real-world C++ application. C++ developers use `new`, `std::vector` or `std::array`... and if they _really_ need legacy C features, then they include non-deprecated `cX`, not deprecated `X.h`. I recommend [these resources](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) if you're serious about learning C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's gibberish. You probably meant `(int(*)[MAXCOL])`.

In C it means that the programmer who wrote it doesn't know how void pointer typecasts work.

In C++ it means that you are allocating an array of arrays. p is an array pointer, so *p is an array of size MAXCOL, and you allocate MAXROW such arrays. The result is a "mangled" 2D array. The avantage of using this rather obscure syntax is that you get a 2D array which has every cell in adjacent memory, something you wouldn't achieve with the more commonly seen pointer-to-pointer dynamic 2D array.

Comment: How are pointer-to-pointer dynamic 2D arrays "more commonly seen"? They are an order of magnitude more complex, and you need loops to populate them.

Comment: It appears to be the most common way to teach dynamic 2D arrays, for some reason, I don't know why, as pointer-to-pointer arrays aren't compatible with static 2D arrays, making it a pain to write generic functions handling either kind.

Comment: Well how very odd! They are _not_ dynamic 2D arrays. They are dynamic arrays of pointers (as you said).

Answer (score 4):

Supposing you meant the uncommented line (the other is the original, which is not valid C)

```
// p = (*)[MAXCOL]malloc(MAXROW*sizeof(*p));
p = (int(*)[MAXCOL])malloc(MAXROW*sizeof(*p));
```

my answer is:

**In C** do not cast the return value of `malloc`. It is at best redundant and may hide an error when present. Simply do

```
p = malloc(MAXROW * sizeof *p);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid code [in C](http://www.ideone.com/jw8S4) [*or* C++](http://www.ideone.com/AYUWA).

So, it doesn't "do" anything at all.

Comment: @Nitin: Have you decided which language you're trying to write, yet? Will you tell us?

Answer (score 1):

As you can learn from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation), `int (*p)[MAXCOL]` is a pointer to an array of MAXCOL integers.

The line `p = (int (*)[MAXCOL])malloc(MAXROW*sizeof(*p));` allocates the memory for an  array of MAXROW arrays of MAXCOL integers (i.e. two dimensional array), and sets `p` to point to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not compiled the following code, but i think it's valid c++-code:

```
    typedef int[MAXROW][MAXCOL] table;

    table *p = new table;
```

This code is only posible if the dimensions of the array are known at compile-time.

This is the way most c++-prgrammers would define p:

```
    using namespace std;
    vector<vector<int> > p;
```

This allows for a more flexible way of programming.

G, folks, it's been a long time since i have programmed K&R C!