# what is the purpose of Declaring b as pointer to array 10 of int

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

see i have seen some code like

```
int (*b)[10];
```

which means

```
declare b as pointer to array 10 of int
```

so i want to ask you what is the purpose of doing this ?

why don't we write instead of that just

```
int array[10];
```

and use as passing address of array.

both are same or any difference ?

**Edit : 
Dont be confuse with**

```
int *b[10];  // this one declare b as array 10 of pointer to int
```

and

```
int (*b)[10];  // this one declare b as pointer to array 10 of int
```

**one more Edit**

see   `int (*b)[10];`

1>will allocate memory for 10 elements of int and the address of that memory will be assigned to b ?

or

2>there will be no memory allocated for array. here it says b is capable of holding address of and int array of 10 element ?

which option is right ?
if any one is right then why one should use this complex syntax rather then using different method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: @trojanfoe  hey this is not duplicate i know the deference among all i want to know what is purpose of using 1st one over 2nd one method.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are not the same thing. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: @pmg ya i know both are different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference actually. In `int b[10]`, `b` is a pointer constant (which means it can be used to modify its underlying data but it *can't* be changed to point to something else). The pointer in `int (*b)[10]` on the other hand *can* be changed to point to something else (as well as being able to change its underlying data of course). So the difference is that by saying that `b` is `int (*b)[10]`; you're hereby *warning* the next developer who sees your code that this `b` can point to something else somewhere in the code. That's why - obviously - don't do that except if you *really* intend to change what `b` is pointing to (otherwise you're just confusing who'll come after you).

Regarding your question, I checked using `sizeof(b)`.

`int (*b)[10]` ==> `sizeof(b)` is 4 (which means no memory allocated - Option 2).

`int b[10]` ==> `sizeof(b)` is 40 (which means memory is allocated as expected - Option 1).

Look at this:

```
int (*b)[10];

int x[10];
b = &x;
```

This compiled. Change the size of the array to anything else. It'll not compile! This means that you're **extremely correct** :-D. Option 2 is written perfectly: This pointer can *only* point to an array of size 10 and *nothing else*.

***[Added as per request of question owner]***

What's the advantage of such a syntax? It's just a feature that's already there, and maybe it's useful for somebody. This is how I understand it (and please correct me if wrong): For example, you can say: `string (*names_of_players_in_soccer_team)[11];` and the advantage is - obviously - restricting the array to be *exactly* 11 names to handle the *application logic* - the team must actually have exactly 11 names. This gives more readability for those who'll read your code, and emphasizes its correctness...

Comment: okey got it man...now why someone write int (*b)[10] instead of just using any generic pointer to any array? whats advantage/meaning of  saying "pointer to array 10 of int"?

Comment: By the way, +1 for the great question: It's my first time to see this syntax... thank you very much - I learned something new.

Comment: i think 1st time in stackoverflow any answerer says thanks to questioners...he he hehe

Comment: -1 Arrays are not constant pointers. Arrays are arrays, and they can decay into pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`int (*b)[10]` is a pointer to an array of int, `int b[10]` *is* an array of int.  (Next time maybe choose different names?)  Perhaps you want to `malloc` the array storage, `b = malloc(sizeof(*b))`.  For this you would need a pointer to array type.

Answer (score 0):

C allows the use of an array's name without a subscript as an rvalue meaning the address of the base of the array.  It also allows a pointer to be implicitly dereferenced with an offset as an array is typically accessed.  The declarations are therefore logically and syntactically equivalent if and only if b never needs to point to a different array or different element of the same array.  Technically, they are dissimilar in that `int b[10]` requires `sizeof(int)*10` bytes to hold the array, and `int (*b)[10]` requires an additional `sizeof(int*)` bytes to hold a pointer to said array.  If the array is declared outside of a function, accessing elements of `int b[10]` may use a smaller opcode and one fewer registers.

I recommend declaring it as you plan to use it.  If you don't know why it might be a pointer, declare it as an array.  If it needs to be dynamically allocated on the heap, reseated, or is declared as a function parameter, it should be a pointer.