# I want to sort character array in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I want to sort arrays with using strcmp . How can do it ?

```
void sort(char s[100][100], int n){
int i, j, cmp;
char tmp[10];

if (n <= 1)
    return; // Already sorted

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
    {
        cmp = strcmp(&s[i][j],&s[i][j+1]);

        if (cmp > 0)
        {
            strcpy(tmp, &s[i][j+1]);
            strcpy(&s[i][j+1],&s[i][j]);
            strcpy(&s[i][j], tmp);
        }
    }
}}
```

I call function for an array like this type :

```
int main(){

char *result[6][6];
int a=0;
    int b=1;
    for(a=0; a<5; a++){
    for(b=1;b<4;b++){
        printf("%s\n", result[a][b]);
        sort(result[a][b],6);
    }

}
}
```

how can I fixed this. Now, I have one warning

Comment: google it, there are thousands of examples

Comment: but I want to ask in this website @redFIVE

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: hey refer to this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809839/bubble-sort-a-character-array-in-alphabetic-order-in-c

this may help you.

Comment: @jospeh so you want people to regurgitate an answer to a simple question which has thousands of examples available online??

Comment: If you think this is a simple question and and I regurgitate to people, why you write comments for this question ? @redFIVE

Comment: Read documentation of [qsort(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) then use it. You'll find many examples of use of `qsort`. Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use meaningful names, example  `length` instead of `b`.
2. Enable complier warnings:  `a=sort(result,6); ... int sort(char *a,int b){` should generate a warning - or get a new compiler.
3. `temp=a[i][j];  ... ... =temp;` attempts to swap pointers.  Code needs to swap the array contents.
4. `char *result[6][6];` is a 6x6 array of pointers.  Code more like wants to use `char result[6][6];` or `char *result[6];`
5. Suggest re-working code to the point that your compiler (with all warnings enabled) no longer complains.

Comment: yes I have warnings I fixed it some warnings but still I have one warning. Now, I edit my post .

Comment: the warning when I call sort funcion in main . [Note] expected 'char (*)[100]' but argument is of type 'char *'

Comment: @joseph Good that you reviewed #2 above.  Also work on 1,3,4,5.  (not all warnings are enabled yet.)  GTG