# For iPad / iPhone apps, how to have an array of points?

Tags: ios, core-animation, quartz-graphics

We can have an `NSMutableArray` object, and add objects to it.

But `CGPoint` is not an object...  are there Point objects suitable to be added to an NSMutableArray object?

I see some code using `NSStringFromCGPoint` to create an `NSString` object so that it can be added to the array, and later use `CGPointFromString` to get the `CGPoint` back... but that just looks too much of a hack...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can store the points in the array using `NSValue` as a wrapper:

```
CGPoint a = CGPointMake(10.0, 10.0);
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:a]];

CGPoint b = [(NSValue *)[array objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
```

Comment: thanks for the solutions for going back and forth between NSValue and CGPoint

Answer (score 6):

You should use the [NSValue class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) with the following methods:

```
+ valueWithCGPoint:
- CGPointValue
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to choose between...

A. c pointer array ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation))

or

B. `NSValue` or your `NSStringFromCGPoint`.
Like this:
  `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 6.6)`]