# From NSMultableArray to CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is that possible to create a CGPoint array in objective-C, I write this code, but it lead to an error!

```
NSMultableArray *result=[[NSMultableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
CGPoint temp=[Self GetPoint];
result[0]=temp; //Error !!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to embed the `CGPoint`s within `NSValue` objects, something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSValue *val1 = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:cgpoint1];
[arr addObject:val1];
// etc.
```

to extract the `CGPoint`s, use this:

```
for (NSValue *value in arr) {
    CGPoint cgpoint = value.pointValue;
    // Use point
}
```

Here's a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to the *NSValue UIKit Additions Class Reference*.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't store `CGPoint` in array. Array only store pointer types objects. you must wrapped up `CGPoint` into `NSValue` then store it in array..

```
NSMultableArray *result=[[NSMultableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
NSValue *pointvalue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
[result addObject:pointvalue];
```

On retrieve time

```
CGPoint *myPoint = [[result objectAtIndex:indexValue] CGPointValue];
```

Also you can wrap other struct type too https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 
`[result addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:player.center]];`

And decode as below

```
CGPoint point = [(NSValue *)[result objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

CGPoint is a struct type, and you can only store objective-c objects into the mutable array. Best way to do it is to wrap it with it NSValue like so `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:temp]`

Similar question here: [For iPad / iPhone apps, how to have an array of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262254/for-ipad-iphone-apps-how-to-have-an-array-of-points)