# What does this character pointer declaration mean?

Tags: c, pointers, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

How is `char (*p)[4];` different from `char *p[4];`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://cdecl.org/

1. `char (*p)[4];` -- declare p as pointer to array 4 of char.
2. `char *p[4];`   -- declare p as array 4 of pointer to char.

Comment: How do I use this "p as pointer to array 4 of char"

Comment: Is *p[0]="Hello"; or *p[0]=(char *)malloc(10); valid for the first declaration

Comment: I mean is it an array of 4 character pointers the first one?

Comment: No, it's a pointer to array, not an array.

Comment: Is it the same of char p[4]; then p in any case will be the base address

Answer (score 4):

`char (*p)[4];`: `p` is a pointer to a `char` array of length 4.

```
                         char [4]
    points to              |
     char [4]              v

   +------+             +------+------+------+------+
   |  p   |------------>|      |      |      |      |
   +------+             +------+------+------+------+
                         char    char   char   char  

   p will point to a char [4] array. Array is not created. 
   p is intended to be assigned at address of a char [4]
```

`char *p[4];` : `p` is an array of length 4, each location of the array is a pointer to `char`

```
              +------+------+------+------+
   p          |      |      |      |      |
an array      +------+------+------+------+
 itself          |      |      |      |
                 v      v      v      v  
               char*  char*  char*  char*

  p is an array and will be allocated in stack (if automatic)
```

Comment: for pointers, picture always helps :)

Comment: In the case of `char (*p)[4]` it's important to note that the declaration does not create the array, only a pointer to one.

Comment: @kittemon updated with the info