# Declaration of pointer to array of pointers

Tags: arrays, pointers

How can I declare 20 times

```
int p[] = { 1,2,3,4,5};
int p[] = { 6,7,8,9,10};
.
.
.
```

Let's say i have a matrix 20x20. each row is a pointer above

Comment: possible duplicate of [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a 20X20 2-dimensional array.

```
int p[][]={{1,2,3,4,5},
           {6,7,8,9,10},
           {11,12,13,14,15},
           .....
           .....
          }
```

**EDIT:**
you can refer to the fifth row using this:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   printf(" %d",p[4][i]);
}
```

Comment: But how will i refer to ( lets say row number 5 ) later?

Comment: you can refer to row number 5 using `p[4]`.

Comment: syntax error.. it refers to the second [] in p[][] declaration