# difference between char *token[32] and char token[32]

Tags: c, pointers, char

This may sound very silly and stupid.I am tyring to understand the difference between

```
char *token[32];
```

and

```
char token[32];
```

char token[32] declares token to be character array that can contain 32 characters.

In case of char *token[32],token holds 32 character pointers.What does these pointers point to? Or more specifically it is the responsibility of the user to allocate memory for what the pointers point to.?

Comment: One's an array of pointers to `char`, and one is an array of `char`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *token[32];
```

is an array of 32 char pointers. i.e. The array can be used as:

```
token[0]=p1;
token[1]=p2;
.....
```

where p1 and p2 can be of `char[]` or `char*` type.

This post may help you understand some more related things other than what asked:

[C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Answer (score 7):

> Now `char *token[32]` declares token to be a pointer to character array that can contain 32 characters.

No. It declares `token` to be an array of 32 char pointers. In other words, in the first case `token` holds 32 characters, in the second case, it holds 32 pointers.

If you wanted to declare a pointer to a character array that held 32 characters, you would write

```
char arr[32];
char (*token)[32] = &arr;
```

Comment: +1 No I put it back once you threw in the last pair of decls (actually the *last* decl, which is more important than allot of people first give credit). I actually love reading almost all your answers =P