# Difference between char *[] and char (*)[]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

What is the difference between

`char *array[10];`

and

`char (*array)[10];` ?

By my understanding,

- **Case 1:**

  - `array` is declared as an array of character arrays of size 10.
  - This is because `[]` has higher precedence than `*`.
- **Case 2:**

  - `array` is declared as a pointer to a character array of size 10.
  - This is because `()` and `[]` have the same precedence and they are evaluated from left-to-right. Then the `*` operator is evaluated.

Is my understanding correct? Even if it is correct, I get incredibly confused. Can someone please explain the difference a little more clearly?

Comment: Now the question. The first is not an array of character arrays. It is simply an array of pointer-to-char. For the second, [`()` and `[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) do indeed have the same precedence as operators, but it is more than that here. these are declarative statements. The parens are used to separate `array` from `[]`, while marrying it to `*`. It sounds like you're pretty close in understanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When trying to interpret C's types, switch the [...] (or group of [...][...]...) with the thing to its left, then read right to left. Thus

```
char *array[10] -> char *[10]array =
```

"`array` is an array of 10 pointers to char"

And

```
char (*array)[10] -> char [10](*array)
```

"`array` is a pointer to an array of 10 chars"

So in the first case, `array` is 10 contiguous pointers, each of which points to a char (which might be a single char, or a sequence of chars such as a string), whereas in the second case, `array` is a single pointer, to an array of 10 contiguous chars.

You can do something similar with function types, switching the parameter list with the thing to its left. For example,

```
char* (*f[10])(int*) -> char* (int*)(*[10]f)
```

"`f` is an array of 10 pointers to functions taking a pointer to int argument and returning a pointer to char".

Comment: Oh wow. This definitely clears away that fog of confusion! Would this kind of interpretation work for _all_ C declarations?

Comment: @AnishRam No, in `int a[3][5]` you don't break `[3][5]` apart, you keep them together as a whole.

Comment: @AnishRam Pretty much (I've added an edit to deal with Alexey's nit). You can extend it to function declarations ... move the parenthesized argument list to the left the same way as moving the array designator.

Comment: @JimBalter You can have a group of `()` as well if a function returns a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a function...

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze, I understand enough C to have figured that much out :D. I'm sure that there will be a few corner cases where this will not work (now I do not know why I asked if this would work for all declarations... ahh the confusion!). Thanks for pointing out one!

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Yes, you can, and you can do the same sort of thing with that, moving the parameter list to the left.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is probably better referred to as an array of character pointers.

Reading complex pointer definitions can be made easier by recognizing a sort of trick to it. I read [this article](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) which helped me out a ton. There is [another one](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) that looks nice as well.

Comment: Great links! Thanks! Will check 'em out.

Comment: Sure, no problem. It becomes pretty simple to read complicated declarations once you learn the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case `array` is an array of 10 pointers to a char, if it's not a function parameter as in `void some_function(char* array[10])`. If it is a function parameter, then it's a pointer to a pointer to a char.

<s>In the second case you have an invalid declaration. See the compilation error [here](http://ideone.com/0z87iT).</s>

In the second case `array` is a pointer to an array of 10 chars.

Comment: The second case was a typo! I edited the post now. Sorry! Also, in the first case, when you say `array` is an array of 10 pointers, I'm not sure I understand. Does this mean `*` gets evaluated before `[]`?

Comment: If you used `*array[0]` in an expression, `array[0]` would evaluate first (as `*(array + 0)`) and then would evaluate `*`, resulting in `*(*(array + 0))`.

Comment: I knew that. I'm just getting quite confused with those declarations. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

**char *array[10];** is an array of 10 char pointers.

example:

```
char *array[10] = {"Hello", "Hai"};
```

where as **char (*array)[10];** is a pointer to an array of 10 char.

second one can point to **char arr[10];**

example

**array = &arr;**

[C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: `an char array of 10 bytes` -- what's that?

Comment: Don't you think `bytes` is superfluous? You already have `char` in there.

Answer (score 0):

check the "Unscrambling C declarations" section in Deep C Secrets or "Complicated declarations" in K&R...