# C function prototype, compile error

Tags: c

C newbie here. Trying to figure out the error in my program.

Function prototype:

```
float* convolve(int (*)[10], int (*)[3], int *, int);
```

actual function:

```
float* convolve(int* ImdataPtr, int* KernelPtr, int* size, int sizeKernel)
```

How it's called in main:

```
float* output;
output = convolve(input,kernel,sizeIm,3);
```

Compile Error:

```
program.c:55:8: error: conflicting types for ‘convolve’
```

Help, please...

Comment: What is `input`, `kernel` and `sizeIm`? Please include the declarations here.

Comment: Look at the error message: it starts off `program.c:55:8`.  That tells you (If I interpreted it right) that (a) the problem is in the `program.c` file, (b) the problem is on like 55, and (c) that the problem is at character 8 of that line.  Error messages are actually helpful in finding problems - don't just dismiss them as your compiler whining.

Comment: @AjMansfield: That is not helpful. The OP already identified the lines causing the error. They understand the location of the problem. The question is about the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the prototype doesn't match. Make sure the types are exactly the same, since `int(*)[10]` and `int(*)[3]` are different types than `int*`:

```
float* convolve(int(*)[10], int(*)[3], int*, int);

float* convolve(int (*ImdataPtr)[10], int (*KernelPtr)[3], int* size, int sizeKernel) {
    // etc
}
```

You can (and probably should) even make them exactly the same, including argument names:

```
float* convolve(int (*ImdataPtr)[10], int (*KernelPtr)[3], int* size, int sizeKernel);

float* convolve(int (*ImdataPtr)[10], int (*KernelPtr)[3], int* size, int sizeKernel) {
    // etc
}
```

I had to look up how to declare these, so you might find the question on [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation) useful too. `int*[3]` is an array of pointers to `int` (just [read it backwards](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html)), but `int(*)[3]` is a pointer to an array of `int`.

Comment: There is no harm in putting argument names in your prototypes.  It's a very good thing for other people who are consuming your header file so they can get a better idea of your intent.

Comment: The arguments are matrix pointers, and i declare them inside main. Well, i guess i can define them before the prototype... Thanks!

Comment: @htann1900 The actual type doesn't matter, what's important is that they match. If you declare an argument as `int**` in the prototype, it needs to be an `int**` when you implement the function.

Comment: @BrendanLong: The prototype does not have parameters of type `int **`. It has parameters of type `int (*)[10]` and `int (*)[3]`, which are different. The former are pointers to pointers. The latter are pointers to arrays.

Comment: The problem is still there after I change the code. In main, I declare: three array and pass their name as convolve(ar1,ar2,ar3,sizeKernel). And I get the message, 'note: expect 'int *', but argument is of type 'int (*)[3]'

Comment: expect 'int asterisk', but... type 'int (asterisk)[3]'

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're right, C's handling of pointers/arrays still confuses me.

Comment: @BrendanLong: `int *[3]` is an array of three pointers to `int`. For a pointer to an array of three `int`, you need `int (*)[3]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks. I actually had to look up some references to figure out how to define parameters like that with a name..

Comment: @htann1900 This version should work, assuming your prototype was correct. If it's not, we'd need to know the actual types of the things you're passing to this function.

Comment: @BrendanLong Yep, that does it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype specifies, for its first and second arguments, pointer to an array of integers , whereas in your function, you are specifying integer pointers alone.

You need to either correct your prototype, or your function definition.

Comment: Yes, of course! That was a bad mistake :\. Thanks for catching it!