# incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[3]' to parameter of type 'const char *

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

With the following code:

```
char randnum[KEYSIZE + 1];
char temp[3];
char buff[KEYSIZE*2 + 1] = {0};  

for (j = 0; i < KEYSIZE; i++) {
    randnum[i]  = rand()%256;
  
    snprintf(temp, 3, "%.2x", (unsigned char)randnum[i]);
    strcat(buff, &temp);
}
```

I'm getting `incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[3]' to parameter of type 'const char *` at `&temp`. This is fixed by using `temp` instead.

I'm trying to understand the error message. I understand `const char *` to be a pointer but I'm not sure what `char (*)[3]` is referring to; specifically the `(*)`. From what I can infer from the fix, I assume this to be a pointer to a pointer (EDIT: pointer). Is this correct?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502256/typedefs-for-complex-data-types and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250397/interpretation-of-int-a3?rq=1

Comment: cdecl could help you in the future. Sadly, it does not work without a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

`&temp` is a pointer to the array itself, and it does indeed have the type `char (*)[3]` (it's a pointer to an array of three `char` elements).

You should pass a pointer to the first element of the string, i.e. `&temp[0]`, which is what plain `temp` *decay* to.

So:

```
strcat(buff, temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

`&temp` is the address of the *whole array*. The array is of type `char [3]`, so the type of the address (pointer) is a pointer to that array, which is expressed as `char (*) [3]`, read it as "pointer to an array of 3 `char`s".

> *I assume this to be a pointer to a pointer.*

No, it's pointer to an array.

Answer (score 1):

The function `strcat` is declared the following way

```
char *strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

As you can see the both its parameters expect expressions of the type `char *` or `const char *`.

In this call of the function

```
strcat(buff, &temp);
```

The first argument expression is indeed has the type `char *` due to the implicit conversion of the array designator `buff` declared like

```
char buff[KEYSIZE*2 + 1] = {0};
```

to a pointer to its first element.

While the second argument expression has the type `char ( * )[3]` because you used the address of operator `&` for the array `temp`

```
&temp
```

You need also to use as the argument the array designator `temp`. In this case it will be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element the similar way as with the array `buff`.

```
strcat(buff, temp);
```

Pay attention to that initially the array `random` should be declared as having the element type `unsigned char`.

```
unsigned char randnum[KEYSIZE + 1];
```

Moreover as the array is not designed to contain a string then it may be declared also like

```
unsigned char randnum[KEYSIZE];
```

char randnum[KEYSIZE + 1];

Answer (score 0):

Arrays decay to pointers.

```
char temp[3];
```

- `temp` decays to pointer to char (`char *`) referring the first element of the array
- `&temp` decays to pointer to array of 3 characters (`char (*)[3]`) referring beginning of the array
- `&temp[n]` decays to pointer to char (`char *`) referring the n-th element of the array

Comment: Address-of operator returns a pointer directly, decay is not the right word in this context, is it?

Comment: Indeed, the `&` and `sizeof` operators are the exceptions from the array decay rule.

Answer (score 0):

The `strcat` function is declared as (C17 7.24.3.1):

```
char *strcat(char * restrict s1,
             const char * restrict s2);
```

Where the important part for the sake of this discussion is that the function expects `char*` for both parameters. Though we can note that a `char*` can be assigned to a `const char*`, but not the other way around.

If we look at the correct use, `strcat(buff, temp);`, then both `buff` and `temp` in that expression are arrays. But in most cases when an array is used in an expression, it "decays" into a pointer to it's first element, it becomes a `char*` in this case.

Formally this "decay" is defined as (C17 6.3.2.1):

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

*However* when you type `&temp`, you stumble upon one of the above mentioned exceptions to this "array decay" rule, namely when used with the unary `&`.

So instead of a `char*` we end up with "address of a `char [3]`". Which has to be expressed with a special pointer type used when pointing at arrays, `char (*)[3]`, known as "pointer to array" or "array pointer".

C has pretty strict rules regarding implicit pointer conversions - it will not accept that a `char(*)[3]` is passed to a parameter expected to be `const char*` - they are incompatible pointer types - it is not a valid form of assignment.

When you know all of this, the compiler error is actually quite self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

`char (*)[3]` is a pointer to an array of size 3.

`temp` in its most "natural" form is of type `char[3]`.  However, because `temp` also points to the first element of the array (which is a `char`), it is allowed to "decay" into a `char*`.

When you take `&temp`, that gives the address of the `temp` variable, *not* an address is located in the array.  Again, in its most "natural" form, `&temp` is of type `char (*)[3]` because it is a pointer to a `char[3]`.  However, note that it is no longer an array type (rather a pointer-to-array), so it is *not* allowed to decay to `char**`.

`strcat(buff, temp);` fixes this because `strcat` wants a `char*`, not a `char (*)[3]`.

Comment: No, `char(*)[3]` and `char**` are fundamentally different and the former cannot decay to the latter. `char**` is a pointer to something that is a `char*`, it might be an array of `char*`, but that's not an array of `char` of length 3.

Comment: `char *[]`, `char (*)[]` and `char **` are completely different

Comment: For comparison: With `char** pp; char(*pa)[3];` you get `sizeof(*pp)` being equal to the size of a pointer (usually 4 or 8 depending on system) whereas `sizeof(*pa)` equals to 3!

Comment: You're right, see my edit.  @Aconcagua I'm not sure that's a valid example since you are dereferencing `pa` and `pp`, so really you are just comparing `char*` vs `char[3]`, not `char**` vs `char(*)[3]`.

Comment: Extending on @0___________ 's comment: Note that a `char*[]`, though, can decay to `char**`...

Comment: @0x5453 Its fully legal to dereference, `sizeof` is not an evaluated context. *Elsewhere* they indeed need to be assigned to valid addresses so that they can be legally dereferenced.

Comment: Actually `char(*)[3]` *can* refer to an array itself (does not in given case, though)! Consider `char array[7][3]; char(*pointer)[3] = array;`...