# How to define a double dimensional array using a single pointer

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

is `char a[64][]` equivalent to `char *a[64]`?

If yes, what if I want to declare `char a[][64]` using a single pointer. How can i do it?

Comment: `char a[64][]` is an error; all dimensions but the last must be defined. Can you clarify what you are asking and perhaps give a small code sample? The meaning of these declarators varies depending on where they appear.

Comment: "char a[64][] is equivalent to char *a[64]" -- No it isn't. As a rank C beginner, you should be asking questions, not making assertions about things you don't understand.

Comment: @JimBalter Ok then why dont you edit my question in a correct way?

Comment: Because I'm not a mind reader, and that's not what edits are for.

Comment: @JimBalter I get it. I respect you but i feel English can be more polite.!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
char a[][64]
```

is similar in pointer representation to

```
char (*a)[64]
```

you can read [this](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html). for 2D-array the second dimension size should be specified.

Comment: -1, just wrong, an array is an array and not a pointer. This transcription is only done for function parameters.

Comment: @JensGustedt. ok ya. i forgot that i cant use the word "equivalent". its similar corresponding representation using pointers.

Comment: Still not much better, fuzzy and not at all helpful. @ajay's answer has it precisely, yours not.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a [pointer to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation):

```
char (*a)[64];
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are not sure about how the following two statements are different.

```
char* a[64];
char (*a)[64];
```

The first one defines `a` to be an array of `64` `char*` objects. Each of those pointers could point to any number of `char`s. `a[0]` could point to an array of `10` `char`s while `a[1]` could point to an array of `20` `char`s. You would do that with:

```
a[0] = malloc(10);
a[1] = malloc(20);
```

The second one defines `a` to be a pointer to `64` chars. You can allocate memory for `a` with:

```
a = malloc(64);
```

You can also allocate memory for `a` with:

```
a = malloc(64*10);
```

In the first case, you can only use `a[0][0]` ...`a[0][63]`. In the second case, you can use `a[0][0]` ... `a[9][63]`

Answer (score 2):

> `char a[64][]` is equivalent to `char *a[64]`.

No, because `char a[64][]` is an error. It attempts to define `a` to an array of `64` elements where each element is of type `char[]` - an incomplete type. You cannot define an array of elements of incomplete type. The size of element must be a fixed known constant. The C99 standard §6.7.5.2 ¶2 says

> **The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type.**

Now if you were to compare `char a[][64]` and `char *a[64]`, then again they are different. That's because the array subscript operator has higher precedence than `*`.

```
// declares an array type a where element type is char[64] - 
// an array of 64 characters. The array a is incomplete type
// because its size is not specified. Also the array a must have
// external linkage.
extern char a[][64];

// you cannot define an array of incomplete type
// therefore the following results in error.
char a[][64];

// however you can leave the array size blank if you 
// initialize it with an array initializer list. The size
// of the array is inferred from the initializer list.
// size of the array is determined to be 3
char a[][2] = {{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}, {'x', 'y'}};

// defines an array of 64 elements where each element is 
// of type char *, i.e., a pointer to a character
char *a[64];
```

If you want to declare a pointer to an array in a function parameter, then you can do the following -

```
void func(char a[][64], int len);
// equivalent to
void func(char (*a)[64], int len);
```

`char (*a)[64]` means *`a`* is a pointer to an object of type `char[64]`, i.e., an array of `64` characters. When an array is passed to a function, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. Therefore, the corresponding function parameter must have the type - `pointer to array's element type`.