# How to differentiate these definition ? how to understand them in order to remember .

Tags: c++, c, arrays

There are some definitions as follows about point and array . I am always puzzled about them. So I think there must some ways to understand them then can help me to remember.

```
int b[10]     
int* b[10]  
int (*b)[10]
int* (*b)[10]
```

Maybe there are more formally-similar that you can add; Can anyone help me to understand them and put them in heart.

Comment: Use the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/859634/1290374

Answer (score 0):

Use this [website](http://cdecl.org/) if your ever confused.

But some people learn visually (in order):

```
b [ 1...10 ]

b [ 1  ...  10]
    |       |
    int     int

b --> [ 1...10 ]

b --> [ 1  ...  10]
        |       |
        int     int
```