# Pointer to an entire row in a 2-D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Suppose I declare a 2-D array as:

```
int a[10][10];
```

As per my understanding, a is double pointer of type int.

Suppose I declare a pointer to an entire row as follows.

```
int (*p)[10];
```

Also `a[0]` points to the row 0, `a[1]` points to row 1...and so on.

So I tried to initialise p as

```
p = a[0];  /* so that p can point to row 0 */
```

I get a compiler warning of incompatible pointer assignment.
But if i write

```
p = a;
```

This works fine.

Can someone tell me what I am undertaking wrong here?

Comment: "As per my understanding, a is double pointer of type int" - no, it's an array of arrays. It's not a pointer. It's not a "double pointer". It's not a pointer-to-pointer. It's an **array** (of arrays). As such, `p[0]` and `p[1]` and `p[i]` (for all 0 <= i < 10) are **not pointers either.** They are arrays as well. They decay into pointers of type `int *`. The type `int *` is not compatible with the type `int (*p)[10]`. You are, however, right in that a **pointer** to the i-th row of the array is of type `int (*)[10]`. So you can write this: `int (*row)[10] = &a[0];`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: *"As per my understanding, a is double pointer of type int"* One of the most widespread and phenomenally persistent misunderstanding around. It is crucial that you learn the difference between and array and a pointer and not be fooled by the syntatical ability to interchange the notations.

Comment: Not a duplicate... I am not concerned with the syntax here alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As per my understanding, a is double pointer of type int.

You are wrong. `a` is of type array of arrays of `int`. Array names converted to pointer to its first element, except when it is an operand of `sizeof` and unary `&`.

> Also `a[0]` points to the row `0`, `a[1]` points to row `1`..and so on.

No. `a[0]` points to the first element of row `0` and `a[1]` points to the first element of row `1` after decay. `&a[0]` will give you the address of row `0`

```
p = &a[0];  // Equivalent to p = a
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is not a double pointer. It's an array of ten arrays of ten ints each. In most uses, it will "decay" into a pointer of type `int (*)[10]`, i.e., a pointer to the first row.

So in the `p = a` assignment, `a` decays as described above, so `p` points to the first row.

If you want to point to another row, you need to explicitly take it's address:

```
p = &a[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

> a is double pointer of type int.

No. `a` is an array of arrays of int.

> Also a[0] points to the row 0

No. `a[0]` *is* the first row, an array of int. In order to *point* to the first row, you need to do `&a[0]`.

Most of the time, you can write `&a[0]` as just `a`, because an array expression, in most (but not all) contexts, is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Another way to think of `&a[0]` is that is effectively the same as `&(*(a+0))`, which is the same as `&*a` and (as adjacent `&*` operators are implicitely reduced) the same `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always assign a pointer to an array, string or a function by just using its name. i.e., if **a[10]** is an array of 10 integer elements you can assign pointer p by using the expression **p = a**, now **'a'** will give the base address of the array. Therefore **'p'** now points to an array of 10 elements.

Same concept can be applied for strings and functions..