# Segmentation fault from accessing 2d array passed to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am using Code:Block.

Compiled the following code(no errors) and while running got segmentation fault.

```
void print(int size, int **a)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";/**Segmentation fault here**/
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    print(size,(int **)a);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using different methods of passing the array:

```
void print(int size, int a[][4])
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    print(size,a);
    return 0;
}
```

I got no error, code ran successfully.

For the first code instead of using `a[i][j]`, I tried with `*(*(a+i)+j)`, got segmentation fault.

Then I debugged the first code at the point of segmentation fault and absorbed the following:

```
> p a
$1 = (int **) 0x22fd30
> p *a
$2 = (int *) 0x200000001
> p **a
Cannot access memory at address 0x200000001
```

I believe that `a` hold the first address of the 2d array. but for p **a there is a different address shown in the error message.

Then I ran the first code in http://ideone.com/ and encountered run time error. Where am I making mistake? and why the debugger showing different address?.

Comment: I am not familiar with `std::vector` and I don't understand what do you mean by "mix `cout` and `printf`"

Comment: A pointer-to-pointer is not a 2D array, simple as that.

Comment: Then `*(*(a+i)+j)` should work right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you index an int**, in your case a[0] for example, the resulting type is int*. If you index that again, as in a[0][0], it will interpret the first element (being the integer 1) (or first two elements on 64-bit) as a pointer to int (int*) and attempt to dereference it, which is obviously incorrect and will usually lead to a segmentation fault.

Your C-style cast (int**) is translated to a reinterpret_cast. Which is why I don't like C-style casts as it's not always obvious what they do.

In short: with your cast to (int**) you're telling the compiler that it's an array of pointers to int, which it isn't: it's an array of int[4]'s.

Edit: my comment about 64-bit only holds for platforms where sizeof(int) is always 4. I believe on linux sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*).

Comment: What are correction(s)/cast type changes should I make to run the code?

Comment: Your second variation, passing as int a[][4] is quite correct.

Comment: Is there any alternative methods for passing? or what changes should I make at `cout<<a[i][j]<<" "` in the first code to run it?

Comment: You cannot work with an int** that, well, isn't. So modifying the function body is not going to fix anything (other than reinterpret_cast back to int[][4] perhaps). Passing as int[][4] is the correct way. It's equivalent to passing a pointer to int[4], so it's no less efficient if that's what you're worried about. If you really wanted to, you *could* cast it to int* or int[] and access it as a 1D array since the elements are stored contiguously anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example

```
void print(int size, int **a)
```

expects second argument of type *pointer to pointer to int*. But here

```
int a[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
print(size,(int **)a);
```

you pass a variable of type *array of 4 arrays of 4 ints*. When you pass an array to function, array decays to pointer to its first element. So actually function `print` gets argument of type `int *[4]` - *pointer to array of 4 ints* which is not what `print` expects. That's an error. You hide this error from compiler telling him that `a` has type `int **`. It doesn't. Hence the segmentation fault.

In your second example

```
void print(int size, int a[][4])
```

expects an argument of type *array of arrays of 4 ints*. It decays to `int *[4]` which is exactly the type of `a` when it decays while passed to `print` function. No error here.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";` with `cout<<a[i*size+j]<<" ";`

Comment: Got address as out put then I tried `*a[i*size+j]` received segmentation fault.

Comment: Yes, if you are using `void print(int size, int a[][4])` version, but I talk about `void print(int size, int **a)`

Answer (score 1):

Problem you are facing is because of Data type of both is different. int arr[][] is different from int ** arr. Lets see from 1-d array when you declare int arr[], arr it is same as int *arr. When you try to access it arr[i] internally what compiler does *(arr+i). But when you declare **int arr[][size] data type of arr is int (*arr)[size]** which is different from int **arr. That's why you get error. see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

Allocation and assignment:

```
int** foo( int N, int M)
{
    int** arr;
    arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*N);
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*M);
    }

    int x=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=x;
            x++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
void print(int size, int a[][4])
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int N=2;
    int M=3;
    int** foo = bar(N,M);
    print(arr,N,M);
}
```