# how, where and why someone would use int (*q)[3];

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was reading this question on stackoverflow
[C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

I came across `int (*q)[3]; // q is a pointer to array of size of 3 integers`
The discussion was quite on understanding complex declarations in C.

Iam unable to understand when it is used and how it is used? how do I dereference it? could anyone explain me with some sample codes, like initializing the pointer and dereferencing it.

```
int main(){
  int a =45;
  int c[3] = {23};
  int b[2][3];
  int d[2][5];
  int (*q)[3];
  b[0][0]=1;
  b[0][1]=2;
  b[0][0]=3;
  q = &a; // warning incompatible pointer type
  q = c;  // warning incompatible pointer type 
  q = b;  // no warnings works fine
  q = d;  // warning incompatible pointer type 
  return 0;
}
```

After trying the above statements, I understood q can point to an array of `n row but 3 column` sized array. How do I dereference those values?

```
 printf("%d",*q); gives some strange value 229352.
```

Could anyone explain me how to initialize and how to dereference the pointers and its memory layout?

Comment: `printf("%d",*q);` is giving you a memory address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `q` can point to an array, you have to

- make its value the address of an array: `q = &c;`, and
- dereference it to get an array: `++(*q)[1]`, `printf("%d", (*q)[2])`, etc.

Note that the rows of `b` are also arrays of type `int[3]`, so you can also assign to `q` the address of each row of `b`:

```
q = b + 0;    // (*q)[i] == b[0][i]
q = b + 1;    // (*q)[i] == b[1][i]
```

(By contrast, the rows of `d` have type `int[5]`, so their addresses are not compatible with the type of `q`, and of course the address of `a` is also not compatible, since the type if `a` is `int`.)

Comment: Thanks, but q = c; is valid case I guess. arrays are replaced with their addresses, q = c and q =&c[0] are both same? right

Comment: @user3205479: The address is just one part of object identity. The *type* is another one. The address of the array is `&c`, that's it. What you call `c` is the address of the first element of the array, which is something different.