# Pointer and array assignment

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

`int val = 7;`

```
int *ptr = &val;
```

**val is a variable of type int and ptr is a pointer to type int**
so the assignment above is right and there is no warning from compiler.

```
int val[5] = {5, 3, 2, 33,557};
int (*ptr)[1]=&val;
```

**val is an array of integers and ptr is a pointer to an array of int**
when run compiler give me a warning:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

please someone explain me what is the differece between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is because the type of the pointer (pointer to length 1 array of `int`) doesn't match the type of the array, with is length 5 array of `int`. You need

```
int (*ptr)[5]=&val;
```

There is no warning in the first example because the type of the pointer on the LHS of the initialization matches the type of the pointer on the RHS.

Comment: I'm thinking that 'int (*ptr)[5]=&val;' is not correct as it (almost) say declare an array of 5 pointers to int, then set the (difficult to say exactly which entry in the 'ptr[]' array)  is being set to the address of 'val'   Perhaps you meant:  'int *ptr[5];  ptr[0] = &val;'

Comment: @user3629249 No, I meant what I wrote. `int (*ptr)[5]` is an pointer to an array of 5 ints.

Comment: @user3629249 Here's [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation).

Comment: @user3629249: The code above is equivalent to `int (*ptr)[5]; ptr = &val;`.  `ptr` is a pointer to a 5-element array of `int`,  `int *ptr[5]` declares an 5-element array of pointers to `int`, which is an entirely different thing, and not what we want here.

Comment: @user3629249 it's cute how you question a 145k user's answer to a trivial question. Hubris is bad!