# Passing 2D array using "*[]" and "[][]" and "(*)[]"?

Tags: c, arrays

Please see the following code snippet:

```
void foo(char str[][MAX_SIZE])
{
    strcpy(str[0], "Hi");
    strcpy(str[1], "Hey");
}

int main(void) {
    int V = 2;
    char str[V][MAX_SIZE];

    foo(str);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
Hi    
Hey
```

When the definition of foo is changed to:

```
void foo(char *str[MAX_SIZE]) { ... } <------------- Runtime error
```

It flashes `Runtime error`

However, wrapping the pointer in brackets works fine:

```
void foo(char (*str)[MAX_SIZE]) { ... } <-------------- Works fine
```

I guess I am getting confused between the different ways to pass a 2D array to a method.

Can you please help me understand what each definition of foo() means, what does it expect and how does it deal with the param it accepts?

Comment: With `void foo(char *str[MAX_SIZE]) { ... }` the code is illegal. Your compiler should tell you this; pay attention to the compiler messages. Even if something only says "warning" treat it as an error unless you are really sure that it's OK (which it is not in this case).

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation

Comment: @M.M: I was experimenting with the things on ideone.com, and it didn't compalin and instead flashed runtime error. I have worked on other compilers and they always complained if something wrong like this is done

Comment: ideone is not very good really, for exactly this reason

Answer (score 5):

These two have the same signature, and are equivalent function declarations (after parameter adjustment):

```
void foo(char str[][MAX_SIZE]);
void foo(char (*str)[MAX_SIZE]);
```

In both, `str` is a pointer to an array of `MAX_SIZE` `chars`. This,

```
void foo(char *str[MAX_SIZE]);
```

however, is a function whose parameter, after adjustment, is pointer to pointer to `char`, i.e. equivalent to

```
void foo(char **str);
```

Comment: *This, however, is a function whose parameter is an array of MAX_SIZE pointers to char* it should be mentioned that here also the parameter is adjusted to a pointer type.

Comment: @ouah Edited. Thanks for pointing that omission out. What I had before was most misleading.

Answer (score 1):

When you use:

```
void foo(char *str[MAX_SIZE]) { ... }
```

it means `str` is an array of pointers of type `char*`. It is equivalent to

```
void foo(char** str) { ... }
```

When you use:

```
void foo(char (*str)[MAX_SIZE]) { ... }
```

or

```
void foo(char str[][MAX_SIZE]) { ... }
```

it means `str` is a pointer to character arrays of size `MAX_SIZE`.

Comment: When you use `char *str[MAX_SIZE]` as a __function parameter__ it means `str` is a _pointer_ to `char*`.