# C programming. Array of pointers, and pointer to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Why I'm getting compiling error in following code? and What is the difference between `int (*p)[4]`, `int *p[4]`, and `int *(p)[4]`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   int (*p)[4];// what is the difference between int (*p)[4],int *p[4], and int *(p)[4]
   int x=0;
   int y=1;
   int z=2;
   p[0]=&x;
   p[1]=&y;
   p[2]=&z;
   for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
      printf("%i\n",*p[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bookmark this page: http://www.cdecl.org/ it translates a C declaration to English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between

```
int *p[4];
```

and

```
int *(p)[4];
```

Both declare `p` to be an array of 4 pointers.

```
int x;
p[0] = &x;
```

is valid for both.

```
int (*p)[4];
```

declares `p` to be a pointer to an array of 4 `int`s.

You can get more details on the difference between

```
int *p[4];
int (*p)[4];
```

at [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation).

Answer (score 1):

- `int (*p)[4]`: `(*p)` is an array of 4 `int` => `p` pointer to an array (array of 4 `int`)
- `int *p[4]` = `int * p[4]`: `p` is an array of 4 `int *`
- `int *(p)[4]`: same as the second

In your case, you should the second form.

Answer (score 1):

This is array of 4 pointers: `int *p[4]`. So array will have 4 pointers, they point to int value. This is the same `int *(p)[4]`.

As for int `(*p)[4];` this is pointer to an array of 4 integers.