# Array pointer in C program

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variable-declaration, pointer-to-array

Here is a C program in textbook, it asks a 3*5 2D array from users and prints the third line.

I am confused with `int* p[5]`. Why here needs to have `[5]`, I think just `int* p` is OK. It can repeatedly add and point to the next memory space in the `int` array. And can anyone explain how pointer works in this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
        int a[3][5];
        int i,j;
        int *p[5];

        p = &a[0];
        printf("Please input:\n");
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for(j = 0; j<5;j++){
                        scanf("%d\n",(*(p+i))+j);
                }
        }
        p = &a[2];
        printf("the third line is:\n");
        for(j = 0; j<5; j++){
                printf("%5d", *((*p)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: In C a 2D array is just an array of a arrays.

Comment: You are correct. No need for `p[5]` here. Clearly, there is no assignment to any `p[i]`.

Comment: `p = &a[0];` should not compile.

Comment: While it might work, it is still wrong and useless. Why not directly index into the 2D array? Anyway, `int *p[5]` is the wrong type. Just another author having trouble with arrays and pointers and the syntax in C. A pointer to the inner array would be `int (*p)[5]` - notice the parenthesis!

Comment: But when I change it to int*p, it reports (*(p+i))+j) becomes to type int rather than int *. I just want to know what happens here?

Comment: @Olaf: Sry, but this comment "*Just another author having trouble ...*" is just useless, because that's why we are here.

Comment: @alk: There is a difference if a beginner writes such code or a book author.

Comment: @Olaf: Ahok, *if* this *is verbatim* from a "book" I understand and follow your comment ... - I thought you were referring to the author of this question, so please excuse.

Comment: @immibis: Correct. Cleaning up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *p[5];
```

is an array of five pointers to `int`.

What you want is a pointer to an array of five `int`s

```
int (*p)[5];
```

because `&a[0]` is the address of the 1st element of `a` which is an `int[5]`.

The compiler should have clearly issued at least a warning on this, if not an error, which would be expected.

More on this here: [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/859634/694576)

Comment: yep, it reports a warning. There should be parenthesis. But most confused me is when I change it to int*p, (*(p+i))+j) becomes to type int rather than int *. Why that happens?

Comment: @JenniferQ appying `*` to `int *` gives `int`

Comment: @JenniferQ: `int * p` defines `p` to point to an `int`. If you apply the de-referencing operator `*` to `p` you get what is points to, that is an `int` here.