# Difference between void **lineptr and (void** )lineptr

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was studying c programming book R&K but can't understand difference between `void **lineptr` and `(void** )lineptr` and can we use them instead of each other?

Comment: They aren't remotely similar - what scenario are you trying to use either/both in?

Comment: Although the answer is perhaps clear in this case, generally context is everything; you should include code examples of real code where you have seen these. I suspect that had you dine that the difference would have been clear to you in any case.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation) for the disambiguation of syntax toward pointers. This is a bit different but it'll explain a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The first is a declaration of a variable `lineptr` of type `void**`, the second is a type cast of the existing variable `lineptr` to the type `void**`.

So, no, they are not interchangeable and are semantically different.