# what is the difference between *p[5] and (*p)[5]?

Tags: c, pointers

While going through an example of pointers I came across a line which was `*p[5]` declares `p` as *an array of 5 pointers* while `(*p)[5]` declares `p` as *a pointer to an array of five elements*. I didn't understand the difference between them.

Could anyone explain it with an example?

Comment: .... you've got an *incomplete* declaration, and 5 != 3!

Comment: This might help: [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: hmm reopened because an explanation was asked for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. int `(*p)[5]`**

is called a **Pointer to an Array(Array Pointer)**. We can declare a pointer that can point to whole array instead of only one element of the array.This pointer is useful when talking about multidimensional arrays.

In this example p is pointer that can point to an array of 5 integers.

```
/*Pointer to an array*/
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *ptr; /*can point to an integer*/
    int (*p)[5];/*can point to an array of 5 integers*/
    int arr[5];
    ptr=arr;/*points to 0th element of arr*/
    p=&arr;/*points to the whole array arr*/
    printf("ptr=%p,p=%p\n",ptr,p);
    ptr++;
    p++;
    printf("ptr=%p,p=%p\n",ptr,p);
    return 0;
}
Output: 
ptr=0012FEAC,p=0012FEAC
ptr=0012FEB0,P=0012FEC0
```

Here    ptr is pointer that points to 0th element of array arr,while p is pointer that points to the whole array arr.The base type of ptr is int while base type of p is ‘an array of 5 integers’.

We know that pointer arithmetic is performed relative to the base size,so if we write p++ then the pointer will be shifted forward by 20 bytes.

**2. Now coming to `*p[5]`:**

This is called **Array of Pointers(Pointer Array)**

Correct syntax is datatype *arrayname[size];

We can declare an array that contains pointers as its elements.Every element of this array is a pointer variable that can hold address of any variable of appropriate type.

```
/*Array of pointers*/
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int *p[5];
    int i,a=5,b=10,c=15;
    p[0]=&a;
    p[1]=&b;
    p[2]=&c;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("p[%d]=%p\t",i,p[i]);
        printf("*p[%d]=%d\n",i,*p[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
Output:
p[0]=0012FEB4   *p[0]=5
p[1]=0012FEA8   *p[1]=10
p[2]=0012FE9C   *p[2]=15
```

I hope this explanation along with examples will clear your concepts.

**Hope this is helpful :)**

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation differs. `*p[3]` resolves to `*(p[3])` but not `(*p)[3]`. Also note that `*p` is equivalent to `p[0]`. Therefore, ...

- `*p[3]` ⇔ `*(p[3])` ⇔ `(p[3])[0]` ⇔ `p[3][0]`
- `(*p)[3]` ⇔ `(p[0])[3]` ⇔ `p[0][3]`

Assuming you have an array of arrays, the difference is shown below:

[image: visualisation]

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is like a sticky note; you write on it where you put the actual object.

An array is a box with equal compartments. It can store objects of the same type.

You have three balls.

*An array of three pointers* is a box that contains three stickers. Each sticker tells where each ball is located (they might not be all in the same place).

*A pointer to an array of three elements* is a sticky note that tells where to find the box. The box contains all tree balls.

Answer (score 0):

Let us see if this helps ,in short, assuming `int`

1) `int *p[3]`

```
 int *p1 = &i;
 int *p2 = &j;
 int *p3 = &k;
```

Instead of the above 3 separate pointers, I can have an array of pointers as `int *p[3]`. Each element in the array can point to `i,j, and k`, all are `ints`

2) `int (*p)[3]`

```
int array[3];
```

If I want a pointer which points to this `array` which have 3 elements, the pointer declaration will be `int (*p)[3]`. This is a pointer pointing to array