# Pointers to array of pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone please explain me what is the difference between the two following declarations:

```
char (*arr_a)[5];
char arr_b[20];
```

and why:

```
sizeof (*arr_b) = sizeof (char)
sizeof (*arr_a) = 5*sizeof(char)
```

Comment: [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation) seems related. (Didn't seem duplicate for me)

Comment: Thinking about writing an *arrays and pointers definitive guide* or something like that.

Comment: @Yaron Scherf `=` != `==`

Comment: I'll just note that `sizeof(char)` is, essentially by definition, [always 1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof#Notes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char (*arr_a)[5];
```

declares a pointer to a 5-element array of `char`.

```
char arr_b[20];
```

declares just a 20-element array of `char`.

So, the output of

```
sizeof (*arr_a)
```

should be *straight forward* -- dereferencing the *pointer to an array* yields the array and it's size is 5.

The following:

```
sizeof (*arr_b)
```

gives 1, because dereferencing the identifier of an array yields the first element of that array, which is of type `char`.

---

One thing you **need to know** to fully understand this is how an array evaluates in an expression:

- In **most** contexts, the array evaluates to a *pointer to its first element*. This is for example the case when you apply indexing to the array. `a[i]` is just synonymous to `*(a+i)`. As the array evaluates to a pointer, this works as expected.
- There are exceptions, notably `sizeof`, which gives you the storage size *of the array itself*. Also, `_Alignof` and `&` don't treat the array as a pointer.

Comment: so *arr_a isn't just a pointer (of size sizeof(void*)) but a pointer to an array and therefore it's size is the size of the array? why isn't sizeof(*arr_a) == sizeof(arr_b)?

Comment: `arr_a` is a pointer. `void` doesn't have a size, but `void *` has (as it's a pointer as well). `arr_b` isn't a pointer but an array. You never tried to get the size of `arr_a`, only the size of `*arr_a` (and `*arr_a` is the array `arr_a` points to)

Comment: so what would i need to write in order to get size: sizeof(XX)==20*sizeof(char) using arr_b?

Comment: @FelixPalmen He actually wrote `*arr_a` in the comment.  It wasn't escaped properly so it shows as italics.

Comment: @dbush I see. Well that's why you can edit comments as well ;)

Comment: @YaronScherf that would be the size of the array, so it's just `sizeof arr_b`. Btw. multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is multiplying by `1`. The size of a `char` is **defined** to be `1`.

Answer (score 2):

`arr_a` is *a pointer to an array of 5  `char`* while `arr_b` is *an array of 20 chars*. `arr_b` is not a pointer unlike `arr_a`.

`sizeof (*arr_b)` equals to `sizeof (char)` because `*arr_b` is of type `char` (equivalent to `arr_b[0]`). For

`sizeof (*arr_a)` equals to `5*sizeof(char)`  because `*arr_a` refers to an array of 5 chars and `sizeof` returns the size of array which is `5`.

Comment: but why do their sizes are different? I would expect that the size of *arr_a will be either size of pointer (sizeof(void*)) or the size of char (like *arr_b)

Comment: @YaronScherf; You are not calculating the size of `arr_a`, but `*arr_a`.

Comment: @haccks He actually wrote `*arr_a` in the comment. It wasn't escaped properly so it shows as italics.

Comment: @dbush; OK. I didn't get that. But still answer is valid.