# C "Error: Invalid initializer"

Tags: c

the following short code snippet results in a invalid initializer error, and as a beginner in C, I do not understand why.

```
unsigned char MES[] = { 0x00, .... };
unsigned char *in[] = &MES;
```

Is this not the correct way to do it?

Comment: ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation

Comment: You define an array of pointers, not a pointer to array.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&MES` is a pointer to an array of `unsigned char`.

`in` is an array of pointers to `unsigned char`.

Try instead :

```
unsigned char (*in)[] = &MES;
```

which makes `in` also a pointer to an array of `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to achieve is the following:

```
unsigned char MES[] = { 0x00 };
unsigned char *in = MES;
```

qualifying `in` as an array (whose size is unknown) as follow

```
unsigned char (*in2)[] = &MES;
```

is not going to add valuable information to it aside that it has a finite size (which is true for any data) and if you print `in` and `in2`

```
printf ("%lx\n", (long unsigned int) in);
printf ("%lx\n", (long unsigned int) in2);
```

the value shall be the same.

Don't confuse the position of the data with the position of its reference.

Using `&MES` is like trying to read the position in memory where the position of the array is written. But this does not exist.

Consider the counterexample:

```
 void *reference_to_memoryarea = malloc(3);
 void **reference_to_the_reference = &reference_to_memoryarea;
```

Here the position exists and *has a position* in memory, where it is stored. And you can write into `*reference_to_the_reference` and generate a good leak

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.