# Passing pointer array to function in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am having trouble passing a pointer array to a function. I will post a simple example that still doesn't work for me. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int transformare(int *v[1])
{
    *v[1] = 10;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int v[1];
    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &v[1]);
    transformare(&v);
    printf("%d", v[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*v[1] = 10;` accesses the array out of bounds

Comment: also, in the function declaration try `int transformare(int *v[])` or `int transformare(int **v)` instead.

Comment: [a pointer to an array is not the same as an array of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: What "pointer array"? `int v[1];` is an array of one `int`. What exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `int *v[1]` in the deceleration and the function deceleration of function `transformare` should be something like `int transformare(int *v[])` and while calling it, you can just call `transformare(v)`

Answer (score 2):

You have *two* problems:

1. Array indexes are zero-based. That is, an array of N elements have indexes from `0` to `N - 1` (inclusive)
2. The declaration `int *v[1]` declares `v` as an array of one pointer to `int`, not as a pointer to an array of one `int`. That would be `int (*v)[1]`. Which is also the type of `&v` from the `main` function.

The solution to the second problem (using the correct type) then leads to a third problem, as it means that `*v[0]` is incorrect due to [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). You need to use parentheses here too, as in `(*v)[0]`.

---

***However*** the second (and the following third) problem is moot, since you don't need to pass arrays "by reference".

Arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element. When using plain `v` when a pointer to `int` is expected, the compiler will automatically translate it as `&v[0]`.

That means you could declare the function to simply take an `int *` as argument, and simply pass plain `v` as the argument.

Answer (score 1):

First, please note that indizes are `0`-based in C, i.e. the first (and - in your case only) element is `v[0]`.

Concerning passing it, just define the parameter as pointer to int, i.e. `int*`. A variable of type `int[1]` will decay to a pointer to int when passed to a function (so there is no need to write `transformare(&v)`, its `transformare(v)`.

```
int transformare(int *v)
{
    v[0] = 10;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int v[1];
    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &v[0]);
    transformare(v);
    printf("%d", v[0]);
    return 0;
}
```