# What's the purpose of 'rectype' in '__STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON' ? How should I make sence of this macro?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

This field is in linux-4.16.12\include\linux\kfifo.h :

```
#define __STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON(datatype, recsize, ptrtype) \
    union { \
        struct __kfifo  kfifo; \
        datatype    *type; \
        const datatype  *const_type; \
        char        (*rectype)[recsize];\
        ptrtype     *ptr; \
        ptrtype const   *ptr_const; \
    }
```

There are less information about this union. So What's the purpose of  rectype and recsize ?

MARK: Could somebody provide reference material about this union ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's “meta-programming” in C – sorry, I'm joking.

The `#define __STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON(datatype, recsize, ptrtype)` is a macro to define a `union`.

It could be used for any kind of declaration, e.g.

```
typedef __STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON(int, 64, int*) IntFiFo;
```

to define a `union` type (alias) or

```
static __STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON(int, 64, int*) intFiFo;
```

to declare a `static` variable.

I must admit that I don't know anything about Linux Kernel programming – that's just what I read from this code (and how it would make sense).

Concerning

```
char        (*rectype)[recsize];
```

`rectype` is a pointer to a `char[recsize]`.

Why the parentheses (`()`)?: They are necessary because if missing this would be another (not intended) type:

```
char        *rectype[recsize];
```

is an array of `char*` with `recsize` elements.

So, pointer to array vs. array of pointers, hence, the parentheses.

`recsize` is one of the macro parameters. IMHO, it must be exclusively used with a constant integral value. Otherwise, it's probably an error. (VLA in a union? No, that doesn't work.)

Last a hint for how to decode confusing C types:

Try [cdecl: C gibberish ⇆ English](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+%28*rectype%29%5B10%5D%3B) if in doubt. With `recsize` it didn't work but replacing `recsize` by a number it provided:

```
char (*rectype)[10];

    declare rectype as pointer to array 10 of char
```

---

After having sent this answer, I googled [c pointer to array site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=c+pointer+to+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=c+pointer+to+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com) out of curiosity and found

[SO: C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/859634/7478597)

as first hit which might be interesting for further reading.