# a "?" before the string

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, endl

I want to use strings to input the path of files:

```
char** argv;
char* mytarget[2]={ (char*)"‪D:\\testlas\\BigOne.pcd",(char*)"‪‪D:\\testlas\\SmallOne.pcd" };
argv = mytarget;
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
   std::cout << "m.name: " << argv[i] <<std::endl;
}
```

However, cout outputs:

```
m.name: ?‪D:\\testlas\\BigOne.pcd 
m.name: ?‪D:\\testlas\\SmallOne.pcd
```

Why is there a `?` before the strings?

I use VS2017 C++11.

I created a new program and used the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string test = "‪abc789";
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

It also outputs `"?abc789"`. Why?

Comment: [Does not duplicate](https://godbolt.org/z/j4fj18). Please post the real, complete code.

Comment: `char* mytarget[2]` is an array of pointers, and `char**` is a pointer to pointer. They're completely different things. See [Converting array of pointers to double pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57839278/995714), [Difference between array of pointers and pointer to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59586561/995714)

Comment: @phuclv The two are compatible here. `mytarget` decays to a pointer to the first element of the `char*` array, and can be assigned to a `char**`. Same reason why for example `main` can be declared with either `char *argv[]` or `char **argv` arguments.

Answer (score 4):

> `std::string test = "‪abc789";`

There is a hidden [LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) character between the opening quote `"` and the first letter `a` (Unicode character `U+202A`, or UTF-8 `E2 80 AA`). Remove it, for example by deleting and retyping the line, then the `?` will go away.

Comment: My bad,sir. I don't quite understand how to remove the "? ". Should I delete something else?Delete the opening quote " or character "a "?

Comment: @AdamPengC Delete and retype the line. Retype it, do *not* copy/paste it back.

Comment: Get it. Thank you sir.

Comment: @AdamPengC hex print the string, or use some character conversion service like https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ you'll see a U+202A at the beginning of the string