# Can someone explain me the meaning of the following construction in C?

Tags: c

Can somebody explain the following construction?

```c
char (*x1)[3];
```

The type of the resulting construction is not clear to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: @klutt good one

Comment: Also see: [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)