# How does this function call and definition line up?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I just came across this function call/declaration pair in C, and I'm a bit confused (I'm a newbie here, but I haven't seen this addressed in any of the material I've been using to learn). The function declaration is given as `bool read_matrix(double a[][M], int n, int m)`, but it is called by `read_matrix((double (*)[M]) a, n, m)`. (M is an integer set by `#define`.) How do these parameters line up with one another? For that matter, what type of object is (*)[M]?

Thanks for clearing up the confusion.

Comment: `(*)[M]` is a [pointer to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation) and since [arrays decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) when passed to a function, an array of arrays like `a[N][M]` decays to a pointer to an array like `(*ptr)[M]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function parameter declared with an array type like in this function declaration

```
bool read_matrix(double a[][M], int n, int m);
```

then it is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the element type.

So this function declaration is equivalent to the declaration

```
bool read_matrix(double ( *a )[M], int n, int m);
```

On the other hand array designators used in expressions as for example as an argument are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So if in a caller of the function you have an array declared like

```
double a[N][M];
```

then passed to the function like

```
read_matrix( a, N, M );
```

it is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int ( ^ )[M]`.

As for the casting in the call you showed

```
read_matrix((double (*)[M]) a, n, m)
```

then if `a` is an array declared as shown above then the casting is redundant. This conversion takes place implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you pass an array expression as a function argument, what the function actually receives is a pointer value:

```
void foo( T *a ) // equivalent to T a[] and T a[N]
{
  ...
}

int main( void )
{
  T arr[N];
  ...
  foo( arr );
  ...
}
```

As a "convenience" C allows you to use array notation for a function parameter declaration, but be aware it will be "adjusted" to be a pointer declaration because the parameter *is* a pointer value, not an array - `T a[N]` and `T a[]` will be interpreted as `T *a`.  Note that this is *only* true in a function parameter declaration, not a regular variable declaration.

Now, just for giggles, replace `T` with the array type `double [M]`.  So instead of being an N-element array of `T`, `arr` is now an N-element array of M-element arrays of `double`:

```
int main( void )
{
  double arr[N][M];
  ...
  foo( arr );
  ...
}
```

In the call to `foo`, the expression `arr` "decays" from type "N-element array of M-element arrays of `double`" to "pointer to M-element array of `double`", or `double (*)[M]`.  So our declaration of `foo` looks like this:

```
void foo( double (*a)[M] ) // equivalent to double a[][M] and double a[N][M]
{
  ...
}
```

And this is why the two seemingly different declarations are equivalent - in the context of a function parameter declaration, `double a[][M]` is interpreted as `double (*a)[M]`.  Again, this is only true for function parameter declarations, not regular variable declarations.