# Casting pointer syntax (to an array address like a smaller sized array) in C language

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, casting

I have an array with 10 `int` elements, and I want to point a pointer to this array, not with full size but half. By this, I can reach the first 5 elements by using `ptr` and the second 5 elements by increasing pointer one `ptr++`.

I just want to know how can I CAST, I don't need to know workarounds or union or struct or anything else...
I just wonder the syntax of such a thing.

Here is the example that I struggle with ;

```
// Pointer to an integer 
int *p;
// Pointer to an array of 5 integers 
int (*ptr)[5]; // this could be void*
int arr[10]; 

// Points to 0th element of the arr. 
p = arr; 

// Points to the whole array arr. 
ptr = (int[5]*)&arr; // when arr sized as 5 , ptr = &arr; gives result a pointer "ptr" with size of 5  

printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", p, ptr); 

p++; 
ptr++; 

printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", p, ptr); 

return 0;
```

Note:
The answer is: ptr = (int(*)[5])&arr; (compiler's warning message helped me out to find this answer, it was not able to convert one to another type ... )

But I really don't know what is the () and why it is not the same thing as int*[5]. I really don't understand the purpose of parenthesis there.

Comment: By the way, the answer is: ptr = (int(*)[5])&arr; but I really don't know what is the (*) and why it is not the same thing int*[5]. I really don't understand the purpose of parenthesis there.

Comment: When you have complex types like this, the easiest thing is to define a typedef.

Comment: @groundbeef See [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you’re asking for, this is what you want:

```
ptr = (int (*)[5]) &arr;
```

The expression `&arr` has type `int (*)[10]` (pointer to 10-element array of `int`).  Since `ptr` has type `int (*)[5]` (pointer to 5-element array of `int`), we just need to cast the result of `&arr` to that type.

Remember the following precedence rules:

```
T *a[N];        // a is an array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N];      // a is a pointer to an array of T
T *f();         // f is a function returning pointer to T
T (*f)();       // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

Unary `*` has a lower precedence than `[]` and `()`, so an expression like `*a[i]` is parsed as `*(a[i])` - you’re dereferencing the result of `a[i]`.  If `a` is a pointer to an array, then you need explicitly group `*` with `a` so you index into what `a` *points to* - `(*a)[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a `typedef` to make the casting easier.

```
typedef int (*int5ptr)[5];

// Pointer to an integer 
int *p;
// Pointer to an array of 5 integers 
int5ptr ptr;
int arr[10]; 

// Points to 0th element of the arr. 
p = arr; 

// Points to the whole array arr. 
ptr = (int5ptr)&arr;

printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", p, ptr); 

p++; 
ptr++; 

printf("p = %p, ptr = %p\n", p, ptr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really want to know direct casting syntax and under the hood. I found it but i still can not get the idea of paranthesis .I would use typedef but I really want to know why int ( * )[5] is not the same thing as   int*[5]  , what is the purpose of (), because when I tried as (int*[5])&addr , compiler gives an error about converting int** to subject type.

Comment: @groundbeef Because `int (*ptr)[5]` and `int *ptr[5]` are different. This analogy could help. So the type is literally your declaration but stripping variable name.

Comment: @groundbeef The parentheses are necessary to override default precedence rules, just as in arithmetic expressions. You need to ensure that it's interpreted as a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers.