# What does `double (* data)[5];` mean?

Tags: c

I understand that `double * price[5];` is an array of pointers. What does `double (* data)[5]` mean? Where is it used for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation

Answer (score 3):

It's a pointer to an array of 5 `double`s. Rarely used.

[cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=double+%28*+data%29%5B5%5D+) is useful to answer these kinds of questions for yourself:

> declare data as pointer to array 5 of double

Comment: Whit a unix-like OS, you do not need the website. Install it and call cdecl then `explain double * price[5];`.

Comment: That site always was way too crude though. `int long x;` syntax error! `static const int x;` syntax error! ...and so on. It doesn't know the C syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It's a *pointer to array* or *array pointer*. Think of it as a pointer that can point at the array as whole rather than just at the first item of the array.

These are mainly there to keep the language type system consistent. If you have an array `double price[5]`, then `&price` gives the address of that array, which needs a corresponding pointer type `double (*) [5]`. This type can only be used to point at an array of 5 `double`, unlike a `double*` which can be used to point at the first item of any array of `double`. So it is less generic but more type safe.

---

One of the main uses for array pointers is dynamic allocation of multi-dimensional arrays. These should be allocated with a single statement like this:

```
int (*array) [x][y][z] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y][z]) );
```

or equivalent

```
int (*array) [x][y][z] = malloc( sizeof *array );
```

That way we get a true "3D array" with all memory allocated adjacently, no heap fragmentation etc. The problem is however that array pointers are cumbersome: to use the pointer in the example above, we would have to de-reference it (like any pointer): `(*array)[i][j][k] = ...`.

To avoid that burdensome syntax, we can instead create an pointer to the first element, which is an array of type `int [y][z]`:

```
int (*array)[y][z] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y][z]) );
...
array[i][j][k] = ... ;
```

where the `array[i]` is pointer arithmetic referring to array number `i` of type `int[y][z]`, `[j]` refers to an array of type `int [z]` and `[k]` refers to an `int`.

---

Other uses of array pointers is increasing type safety of arrays passed to functions, or returning a pointer to an array from a function.