# C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation (extended)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, declaration

[There is a post where different pointer notations are explained:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

```
int* arr1[8]; // An array of int pointers.
int (*arr2)[8]; // A pointer to an array of integers
int *(arr3[8]); // The same as the first one
```

But it is also possible to define this:

```
int (*arr4[8])
```

Here everything except the datatype name is enclosed with parentheses. How is it different from the firts three options?

I tried to enclose it like `(int *arr4[8])` as well, but seems like this is not valid in C.

I'm also curious about constructions like this:

```
int (*arr5[8])[8]
```

Not sure, but I presume this is something like *an array of pointers to an array of integers*.
If I need to specify a pointer to such construction, I reckon this is something like this:

```
int (*(*arr5[8]))[8]
```

And if I throw the outermost parentheses aside, I guess this is something like *an array of pointers to an array of pointers to integers*, is it?

```
int *(*arr5[8])[8]
```

Is all that correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://cdecl.org

Comment: `int (*arr4[8])` is the same as `int* arr1[8];`

Comment: Using `typedef` is very useful when nesting these deeply as in your last examples.

Comment: @Barmar well, yes, that enhances readability. Still, did I interpret those constructions right?

Comment: Use the site linked to above, that's what I would do if I were going to answer the question.

Comment: @Barmar just have been trying to find out how in works. It's awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `int (*arr4[8])`
>
> Here everything except the datatype name is enclosed with parentheses. How is it different from the firts three options?

The only times parentheses matter is when they change the default precedence of operators.  Postfix `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than unary `*` in both declarators and expressions, so `*arr4[8]` is parsed as `*(arr4[8])`.  `(*arr4[8])` doesn't affect the precedence of either `*` or `[]`, so it's identical to writing `*(arr4[8])` and `*arr4[8]`.  However, with `(*arr3)[8]`, they *do* change that precedence, explicitly grouping the `*` operator with `arr`.

> I tried to enclose it like `(int *arr4[8])` as well, but seems like this is not valid in C.

It is not - the syntax doesn't allow it.

> `int (*arr5[8])[8]`
>
> Not sure, but I presume this is something like an array of pointers to an array of integers.

Precisely speaking, `arr5` is an 8-element array of pointers to 8-element arrays of `int`.  Graphically, it would look something like this:

```
      +---+                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+     
arr5: |   | arr5[0] ----------> |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
      +---+                     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      |   | arr5[1] --------+
      +---+                 |   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      |   | arr5[2] ------+ +-> |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
      +---+               |     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
       ...                |     
                          |     +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                          +---> |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
                                +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You would index each element as `(*arr5[i])[j]` - you don't want to index into each `arr5[i]`, you want to index into what each `arr5[i]` *points to*.  The declarator tells you this up front - you don't have to puzzle it out on your own.  The structure of the declarator mirrors the structure of the expression.

Note that this declaration doesn't create the 8-element arrays of `int` - it *only* creates an 8-element array of pointers.  You would either need to dynamically allocate the memory for each `arr5[i]` to point to, like:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
  arr5[i] = malloc( sizeof *arr5[i] ); // sizeof *arr5[i] == sizeof (int [8])
```

or have a bunch of arrays already declared:

```
int foo[8];
int bar[8];
int bletch[8];
...
int (*arr5[8])[8] = { &foo, &bar, &bletch, ... };
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for explaining the precedence

Answer (score 1):

You may enclose declarators in parentheses.

This declaration

```
int (*arr4[8]);
```

declares an array of 8 elements of the type `int *`. It is the same as to write

```
int * arr4[8];
```

As for this declaration

```
int (*(*arr5[8]))[8];
```

then to make it clear consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a1[8] = { [0] = 10 };
    int a2[8] = { [0] = 20 };
    
    int ( *p1 )[8] = &a1;
    int ( *p2 )[8] = &a2;
    
    int (*(*arr5[8]))[8] =
    {
        &p1, &p2
    };
    
    printf( "%d\n", ( **arr5[0] )[0] );
    printf( "%d\n", ( **arr5[1] )[0] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10
20
```

That is this declaration

```
int (*(*arr5[8]))[8]
```

declares an array of pointers to pointers to arrays of the type `int[8]`.