# How is `int (*arr1)[10]` different from `int arr2[10]`?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

As I was going though some code examples, I encountered this way of declaration:

```
int (*arr1)[10]
```

I am aware of another way of array declaration in C:

```
int arr2[10]
```

Is `int (*arr1)[10]` doing the same as `int arr2[10]`?

Comment: [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: Use [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*arr1%29%5B10%5D) for complex expressions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C pointer to array/array of pointers disambiguation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation)

Comment: @Evg pretty nice link

Comment: arr2 an array of integers.  arr1 is a pointer to an array of integers.   They are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

The differences are as follows:

```
int (*arr1)[10];    // arr1 is a pointer to a 10-element array of int
int *arr2[10];      // arr2 is a 10-element array of pointer to int
```

This is important - despite the `[10]` at the end, `arr1` is *not* an array; it only stores a *single* pointer value, which is the address of some 10-element array of `int`.

Pointers to arrays crop up in two main circumstances - when an N-dimensional array expression "decays" to a pointer expression, and when we're allocating memory for an N-dimensional array.

First, the decay rule - except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or the unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  You've probably seen this before with code like:

```
int arr[10];
int *p = arr; // arr "decays" to a pointer to its first element
```

The expression `arr` "decays" from type "10-element array of `int`" to type "pointer to `int`".

The exact same thing happens with 2D arrays:

```
int arr[5][10];
int (*p)[10] = arr;
```

The expression `arr` "decays" from type "5-element array of 10-element array of `int`" to type "pointer to 10-element array of `int`".

You can also obtain a pointer to a 1D array directly with the unary `&` operator:

```
int arr[10];
int (*p)[10] = &arr; // note presence of & operator here
```

but that's not very common.

Another use for pointers to arrays is when we want to dynamically allocate a *contiguous* 2D (or higher-dimensioned) array:

```
int (*p)[10] = malloc( sizeof *p * 5 ); // allocates space for a 5x10 array of int
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is "10-element array of `int`", or `int [10]`, so `sizeof *p` is equivalent to `sizeof (int [10])`, so the `malloc` call sets aside enough space for 5 10-element arrays of `int`.  You would index into this array like any other 2D array: `p[i][j] = some_value();`. The rows of this array are contiguous in memory and all the same length, and it only requires a single call to `free` to deallocate.

You've probably seen code that dynamically allocates 2D arrays in multiple steps - first you allocate an array of pointers, then for each of those pointers you allocate an array of the target type, like so:

```
int **p = malloc( sizeof *p * R ); // allocates an R-element array of pointer to int
if ( p )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < R; i++ )
  {
    p[i] = malloc( sizeof *p[i] * C ); // allocates a C-element array of int
  }
}
```

The difference here is that in the second case, the rows are not adjacent in memory - it's not a single, continuous block.  Also, different rows may be different lengths (what's sometimes called a "jagged" array).  You also have to `free` each row separately before freeing `p`.

The basic rules of pointer declarations are:

```
T *p;       // p is a pointer to T
T *a[N];    // a is an array of pointer to T
T *f();     // f is a function returning pointer to T

T (*a)[N];  // a is a pointer to an N-element array of T
T (*f)();   // f is a pointer to a function returning T

T const *p; // p is a non-const pointer to const T - you can modify p to point
            // to a different object, but you cannot modify the thing p points to
const T *p; // same as above

T * const p; // p is a const pointer to non-const T - you can modify what p
             // p points to, but you can't modify p to point to a different object
             // (which means p needs to be initialized to a valid pointer value
             // when it's declared).

T const * const p; // p is a const pointer to const T - you can't update either
                   // p or *p
const T * const p; // same as above.
```

Answer (score 0):

If in this specification

```
int (*arr1)[10]
```

you will remove the term in the parentheses you will get `int[10]`. The term in the parentheses denotes a pointer. So you have a pointer to an array of 10 elements of the type int. For example

```
int a[10];
int ( *arr )[10] = &a;
```

Dereferencing the pointer you will get the array (the object of the array type pointed to by the pointer) itself.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int ( *arr )[N] = &a;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ( *arr )[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Instead of these declarations you could use declarations based on a typedef like

```
enum { N = 10 };
typedef int Array[N];

Array a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
Array *arr = &a;
```