# How to properly allocate true 3D array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently struggling to find a proper way to dynamically allocate a true 3D array in C89. The purpose of this is to create a storage for a 3D Cartesian grid. Is it possible to do so without the so-called three-star programming?

Comment: What (do you think) is "a true 3D array"? How is it differ from simple arrays like `int hoge[64][64][64];`?

Comment: Whats wrong with tree-star? If you want 3D array, you need "pointer to pointer to pointer".. each of those will point to "pointer to pointer" and each of those would point to "pointer". whats wrong with that?

Comment: C89? What cruel situation are you stuck in? Do you need help? Blink three times if you need a rescue.

Comment: Not possible to `malloc` a 3D array without `int***` in standard C. Sorry.

Comment: There's only semantic differences between `int p[X][Y][Z]` and `int p[X * Y * Z]`, they're both "3D" arrays.

Comment: @DarkAtom This is not true.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Allocating a 1D array and treating it as 3D by indexing it manually isn't the same as allocating a 3D array.

Comment: `void*` may be useful to hide `int**` and avoid three-star, but I won't recommend this.

Comment: @DarkAtom You can do something like `int (*p)[10][10][10] = malloc(10*10*10*sizeof(int));` - and `p` will be a pointer to a perfectly contiguous 3D array with all the typechecking.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But then what is the point of dynamic memory allocation? You could simply declare a static array with those bounds.

Comment: @DarkAtom To see what Eugene is driving at, see my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66017818/how-to-display-the-individual-elements-of-two-identical-columns-inside-a-2d-arra/66035985#66035985 Look at the code in the UPDATE section, particularly the `ARRDEF` macro.

Comment: @DarkAtom This is another story. You can have it VLA-like `int (*p)[x][y][z] = malloc(x*y*z*sizeof(int))`. But without the downsides of VLAs related to their stack nature. But well, not in C89.

Comment: From my current understanding a pointer-to-pointer isn't an array so in this way I am only mimicking them..

Comment: @miker You are very right about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a "true" 3D array I'm assuming you mean that all the elements are in one contiguous block.  In that case your best option would be something like this:

```
/**
 * Allocate an NxRxC array of some arbitrary type T
 */
T (*arr)[R][C] = malloc( sizeof *arr * N );
```

which gives you

```
     T (*)[R][C]        T 
     +---+             +---+      
arr: |   | ----------->|   | arr[0][0][0]
     +---+             +---+
                       |   | arr[0][0][1]
                       +---+
                        ...
                       +---+
                       |   | arr[0][0][C-1]
                       +---+
                       |   | arr[0][1][0]
                       +---+
                        ...
                       +---+ 
                       |   | arr[0][R-1][C-1]
                       +---+
                       |   | arr[1][0][0] 
                       +---+
                        ...
```

You would only use a triple pointer for a piecemeal, "jagged" array allocation (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
T ***a = malloc( sizeof *a * N )
for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
  a[i] = malloc( sizeof *a[i] * R );
  for ( size_t j = 0; j < C; j++ )
  {
    a[i][j] = malloc( sizeof *a[i][j] * C );
  }
}
```

which gives you something like this:

```
   T ***        T**             T*                  T
   +---+       +---+            +---+              +---+---+---+---+---+
a: |   |------>|   | a[0] ----->|   | a[0][0] ---->|   |   |   |   |   |...
   +---+       +---+            +---+              +---+---+---+---+---+
               |   | a[1] --+   |   | a[0][1] --+  
               +---+        |   +---+           |  +---+---+---+---+---+
                ...         |    ...            +->|   |   |   |   |   |...
                            |                      +---+---+---+---+---+
                            |
                            |   +---+              +---+---+---+---+---+
                            +-->|   | a[1][0] ---->|   |   |   |   |   |...
                                +---+              +---+---+---+---+---+
                                |   | a[1][1] --+
                                +---+           |  +---+---+---+---+---+
                                 ...            +->|   |   |   |   |   |...
                                                   +---+---+---+---+---+
```

You would use this second method when rows don't have to be the same length, or when you absolutely cannot allocate the whole array in a single contiguous block.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. Some may or may not suit your needs.

**Static arrays**

If the size of the array is a compile-time constant, you can declare it like this:

```
int arr[3][4][5];
```

**Variable-length arrays**

Same as above, but the array size doesn't need to be a compile-time constant. This only works for local arrays and only in C99, though, so it won't work for you.

```
int arr[n][m][p];
```

Or, if you want it dynamically allocated, as suggested by @Eugene Sh:

```
int (*arr)[m][p] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n * m * p);
```

**Dynamic memory allocation**

Using `malloc`:

```
int*** arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n * m * p);
```

Or, if you don't want triple pointers:

```
int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * n * m * p);
```

But this array needs to be indexed as `arr[i*p + j*m + k]` instead of the usual `arr[i][j][k]`.

Answer (score 1):

The function malloc does not know what kind of an array you are trying to allocate. It just allocates an extent of memory of the size specified by the user.

What you need is to declare correctly the pointer that will point to the allocated memory that you could use an expression like

```
a[i][j][k]
```

to access elements of the allocated array where i, j, and k are some indices.

You can allocate a three dimensional array for example the following way

```
enum { N1 = 2, N2 = 3, N3 = 4 };

int ( *a )[N2][N3] = malloc( sizeof( int[N1][N2][N3] ) );
```

or

```
int ( *a )[N2][N3] = malloc( N1 * sizeof( int[N2][N3] ) );
```

or

```
int ( *a )[N2][N3] = malloc( N1 * sizeof( *a ) );
```

or like

```
int ( *a )[N2][N3] = malloc( N1 * N2 * sizeof( int[N3] ) );
```

or

```
int ( *a )[N2][N3] = malloc( N1 * N2 * sizeof( **a ) );
```

or even like

```
int ( *a )[N2][N3] = malloc( N1 * N2 * N3 * sizeof( int ) );
```

or

```
int ( *a )[N2][N3] = malloc( N1 * N2 * N3 * sizeof( ***a ) );
```

If your compiler supports variable length arrays then it is not necessary that N1, N2, and N3 would be integer constant expressions.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N1 = 2, N2 = 3, N3 = 4 };
    int ( *a )[N2][N3];
    
    a  = malloc( sizeof( int[N1][N2][N3] ) );
    
    free( a );
    
    a = malloc( N1 * sizeof( int[N2][N3] ) );
    
    free( a );
    
    a = malloc( N1 * sizeof( *a ) );
    
    free( a );
    
    a = malloc( N1 * N2 * sizeof( int[N3] ) );
    
    free( a );
    
    a = malloc( N1 * N2 * sizeof( **a ) );
    
    free( a );
    
    a = malloc( N1 * N2 * N3 * sizeof( int ) );
    
    free( a );
    
    a = malloc( N1 * N2 * N3 * sizeof( ***a ) );
    
    free( a );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler does not support variable length arrays and you need to determine sizes of a three-dimensional array at run-time then you can allocate a one-dimensional array and using an index expression simulate a three dimensional array or you will need to allocate arrays of arrays.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N1 = 2, N2 = 3, N3 = 4 };

    int ***a = malloc( N1 * sizeof( int ** ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N1; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = malloc( N2 * sizeof( int * ) );
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N2; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = malloc( N3 * sizeof( int ) );
        }
    }
    
    //...
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N1; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N2; j++ )
        {
            free( a[i][j] );
        }
        free( a[i] );
    }
    
    free( a );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your proposals but sadly it seems they don't need my needs...  My aim is to allocate the array once its dimensions are determined so N1, N2, N3 won't be constant expressions.  Im C89 I also cannot decalere int (*a) [N2][N3] after I determine the required dimensions.

Comment: @miker As I wrote in the answer in this case you have only two choices either allocate one one-dimensional array and use an expression of indices that will simulate an access of a three dimensional array or allocate one-dimensional arrays )of pointers) of arrays.